# How do I create a heterogeneous Array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

In javascript, we can do:

```
["a string", 10, {x : 1}, function() {}].push("another value");
```

What is the Scala equivalent?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Arrays in Scala are very much homogeneous.  This is because Scala is a statically typed language.  If you really need pseudo-heterogeneous features, you need to use an immutable data structure that is parametrized covariantly (most immutable data structures are).  `List` is the canonical example there, but [`Vector`](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/misc/implementing-persistent-vectors-in-scala/final/Vector.scala) is also an option.  Then you can do something like this:

```
Vector("a string", 10, Map("x" -> 1), ()=>()) + "another value"
```

The result will be of type `Vector[Any]`.  Not very useful in terms of static typing, but everything will be in there as promised.

Incidentally, the "literal syntax" for *arrays* in Scala is as follows:

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4)     // => Array[Int] containing [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**See also**: [More info on persistent vectors](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/implementing-persistent-vectors-in-scala/)

Comment: This answer is awfully confusing -- the fact is that the OP's example works perfectly fine with a Scala `Array`, as @soc's answer shows.

There are other options like `List` and `Vector`, but the reasons to use them or not use them have nothing to do with whether the use case is homogeneous or "pseudo-heterogeneous".

Comment: The answer is laced with jargon which may make it confusing. It also explains a lot if you get what he's saying. I suspect this phrasing was done on purpose, as the OP is coming from javascript.

Comment: No, this is really how Scala natives speak.  It's totally normal.  (And I mean this honestly; I'm not at all trying to be sarcastic.)

Comment: Isn't it also possible to pack all these things into a `Tuple`, as " a tuple combines a fixed number of items together so that they can be passed around as a whole. Unlike an array or list, a tuple can hold objects with different types." (taken from http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html) ?

Answer (score 19):

Scala will choose the most specific Array element type which can hold all values, in this case it needs the most general type `Any` which is a supertype of every other type:

```
Array("a string", 10, new { val x = 1 }, () => ()) :+ "another value"
```

The resulting array will be of type `Array[Any]`.

Answer (score 4):

Scala might get the ability for a "heterogeneous" list soon:
[HList in Scala](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2008/09/hlist-in-scala-revisited-or-scala.html)

Comment: Although notice that HList doesn't change the language at all, so if HList can do it, it's always been in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would probably use tuples, as herom mentions in a comment.

```
scala> ("a string", 10, (1), () => {})
res1: (java.lang.String, Int, Int, () => Unit) = (a string,10,1,<function0>)
```

But you cannot append to such structures easily.

The HList mentioned by ePharaoh is "made for this" but I would probably stay clear of it myself. It's heavy on type programming and therefore may carry surprising loads with it (i.e. creating a lot of classes when compiled). Just be careful. A HList of the above (needs MetaScala library) would be (not proven since I don't use MetaScala):

```
scala> "a string" :: 10 :: (1) :: () => {} :: HNil
```

You can append etc. (well, at least prepend) to such a list, and it will know the types. Prepending creates a new type that has the old type as the tail.

Then there's one approach not mentioned yet. Classes (especially case classes) are very light on Scala and you can make them as one-liners:

```
scala> case class MyThing( str: String, int: Int, x: Int, f: () => Unit )
defined class MyThing

scala> MyThing( "a string", 10, 1, ()=>{} )
res2: MyThing = MyThing(a string,10,1,<function0>)
```

Of course, this will not handle appending either.