# Is it possible to "curry" higher-kinded types in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, currying, higher-kinded-types, kind-projector

Let's suppose I have a trait with two type parameters, e.g.

```
trait Qux[A, B]
```

and another trait with a higher-kinded type parameter, e.g.

```
trait Turkle[C[_]]
```

I'd like to be able to substitute a fixed value for one of the type parameters for `Qux`, so that it can be used to parametrize `Turkle`.

Here's an example (of code that doesn't make sense in Scala!):

```
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[Qux[A, _]]
```

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this effect?

Comment: This compiles, although I have absolutely no idea if this is what you want: `type QuxApplied[A] = Qux[A, _]; trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[QuxApplied]`

Comment: @huynhjl - My guess is that it is supposed to be the same `A`, which is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Jason Zaugg came up with the most succinct way to do this:

```
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[({type x[a]=Qux[A, a]})#x]
```

IntelliJ's Scala plugin will optionally collapse this to:

```
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[x[a]=Qux[A, a]]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to have an "inline" solution.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like this?

```
trait QuxWithString[A] extends Qux[A, String]
new Turkle[QuxWithString]{}
```

This is the analog to partial application for types.

Answer (score 2):

```
trait Turkle[C[_]]
trait Qux[A,B]
trait Wraps[A] {
  type Jkz[X] = Qux[A,X]
  trait Baz extends Turkle[Jkz]
}
```

Comment: This is actually pretty good. In my use cases it's not so unusual to have nested traits anyway, so there's little feeling of writing boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler plugin [kind projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) allows this as well:

```
// Explicit lambda, greek letters
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[λ[α=>Qux[A,α]]]

// Explicit lambda, normal letters
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[Lambda[a=>Qux[A,a]]]

// No explicit lambda, ? placeholder    
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[Qux[A,?]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala 3 is proposing [SIP: Underscore Syntax for Type Lambdas #5379](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/5379) such that the following might be possible

```
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[Qux[A, _]]
```

Scala 3 natively provides [type lambdas](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas.html) using `[X] =>> F[X]` syntax so [try](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UThj4fr4RIW82um7wfN15g)

```
trait Baz[A] extends Turkle[[B] =>> Qux[A, B]]
```