# Context bound for nested type

Tags: scala, polymorphism, implicits

Is it possible to create somehow a context bound for a nested type? Something like this:

```
def f[T : U[List]](a: T)
```

Ofc, this is not Scala syntax, but illustrates what I want to achieve, that is, get a bound on an implicit `U[List[T]]`. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with type alias:

```
type UList[X] = U[List[X]]
def f[T : UList](a: T)
```

or

```
def f[T:({type UL[X] = U[List[X]]})#UL](a: T)
```

Comment: Well, I was expecting something without the alias, but not the abomination of the second solution :) I will wait a bit and if there's nothing better I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @kaktusito I am very unsatisfied  with current synthax for type curring in scala too.

Comment: Seems like there are some old questions on the topic (as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247817/is-it-possible-to-curry-higher-kinded-types-in-scala) but then there wasn't attention to it anymore.

Comment: If you don't like the syntax for type currying (and who does?) here is the kind projector compiler plugin that allows for a more natural one.