# How to help scala type inferencer?

Tags: scala, type-inference

Scala type inference system has its limitations.

For example in the following classes. I'd like to have a factory `FooFactory` that creates instances of `Foo` and a `FooChanger` that can modify instances created by the `FooFactory`.

After I create my `Foo` and my `FooChanger` with the factory, I'd like to use the changer in objects created by the `FooFactory` object, however, scala is not able to recognize that the type `myOwnChanger.fooFactory.Foo` and `factory.Foo` are the same.

A possible solution is to cast, or also, to use only `factory.theFooChanger.fooFactory` in all client code. Both are ugly solutions and force the client to do something unnatural.

**The question is:** What can be done to avoid the problem for the client? Is there a way to tell the inferencer that for the rest of the code `myOwnChanger.fooFactory.Foo` and `factory.Foo` are the same?

```
class FooChangerFactory(val fooFactory: FooFactory) {
class FooChanger
  def change(foo: fooFactory.Foo) = foo
}

class FooFactory(i: Int) {
  class Foo private[FooFactory] ()

  def create = new Foo
  def theFooChanger = new FooChangerFactory(this)
}

val factory = new FooFactory(1)
val myFoo = factory.create
val myOwnChanger = factory.theFooChanger
myOwnChanger.change(myFoo) // error here! it expects myOwnChanger.fooFactory.Foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
def change(foo: fooFactory.Foo) = foo
```

with

```
def change(foo: FooFactory#Foo) = foo
```

**The problem exists because, in Scala, inner types are path-dependent** (i.e. for each `FooFactory` instance, its inner type `Foo` is "unique" to that instance). **The usage of `#` is called [type projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala)**. The way to think of this is that `FooFactory#Foo` is the common supertype of all the path-dependent `Foo` in all instances of `FooFactory`.