# Access type member of an extension of an abstract class in Scala

Tags: scala, oop, abstract-class, parameterized-types

I've got an abstract class in scala:

```
abstract class Agent {
  type geneType
  val genome: Array[geneType]
  implicit def geneTag: reflect.ClassTag[geneType]
  def copy(newGenome: Array[geneType]): AgentT[geneType]
}
object Agent { type AgentT[A] = Agent { type geneType = A }}
```

I've also got an extension of that class:

```
case class Prisoner(initGenome: Array[Boolean]) extends Agent {
  type geneType = Boolean
  val genome = initGenome
  def geneTag = implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[Boolean]]
  def copy(newGenome: Array[geneType], memSize:Int):AgentT[Boolean] = new Prisoner(newGenome:Array[Boolean], memSize: Int)
}
```

I'd like to define a function that is parametrized by the geneType of an extension of Agent. I'm not sure how to access that type member of the class, though.  Say it's the following function:

```
def slice[A](parentA: AgentT[A], parentB: AgentT[A]): (AgentT[A], AgentT[A]) = {
  val genomeSize = parentA.genome.length
  require (parentB.genome.length == genomeSize)
  import parentA.geneTag

  val index    = (math.random * genomeSize + 0.5).toInt
  val (aInit, aTail) = parentA.genome.splitAt(index)
  val (bInit, bTail) = parentB.genome.splitAt(index)
  val genomeA  = Array.concat(aInit, bTail)
  val genomeB  = Array.concat(bInit, aTail)
  (parentA.copy(genomeA), parentB.copy(genomeB))
}
```

Furthermore, say that this function is being called from within some other process, like this one:

```
abstract class Simulation[E <: Agent](population: Array[E]) {

  var pop = population
  // HERE's WHERE I'm CONFUSED
  val (child1, child2) = slice[ ????????? ](pop(1), pop(2))

}
```

I was trying stuff like *E.geneTag* and *E.geneType*, and those didn't work.  If I have an *object* of type *Prisoner*, I can access its *geneType*, Boolean, with

```
val pris = new Prisoner(genome, memSize)
pris.geneTag
```

But I'd like to access the *geneTag* associated with a **type** that extends *Agent*.
I'd like to figure out how to do something like *Prisoner.geneTag*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You were close with `E.geneType`. You need a *type projection* here, written `E#geneType`.

See this other SO question about type projections in general: [What does the `#` operator mean in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala)

Comment: I get error: No ClassTag available for E#geneType.  I tried E#geneType:ClassTag as well as suggested by another SO post with a different OP.

Comment: Right, you also need a `ClassTag` from within `Simulation`. But you cannot conjure one up from nowhere. You'll have to require it as an additional parameter in your class:
`abstract class Simulation[E <: Agent](population: Array[E])(implicit ct: ClassTag[E#geneType]) {`.
Not sure this is going to work, though. I've never tried requiring a `ClassTag` of a type projection...

Comment: that worked out, but then there were issues with the slice function due to Array invariance. I will investigate this more thoroughly.