# Referring abstract type member of a type parameter

Tags: scala, abstract-type, type-members, type-projection

My scenario is like:

```
trait A {
    type B
    def foo(b: B)
}

trait C[D <: A] {
    val d: D
    def createB(): D#B
    def bar() {
        d.foo(createB)
    }
}
```

In REPL, it complains

```
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : D#B
 required: C.this.d.B
       a.bar(createB())
```

What's wrong with this ? And (if possible at all) how to correct this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D#B` is a type projection, and is not the same as `d.B`. You have a type mismatch because in `foo`, `B`actually meant `this.B`, which as said is not the same as `D#B` (the latter being more general).
Informally, you can think of `D#B`as representing any possible type that the abstract type `B` can take for any instance of `D`, while `d.B` is the type of `B` for the specific instance `d`.

See [What does the `#` operator mean in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala) and [What is meant by Scala's path-dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types) for some context.

One way to make it compile it is by changing `createB`'s return type to `d.B`:

```
def createB(): d.B
```

However in many cases such a solution is too restrictive because you are tied to the specific instance `d`, which might not be what you had in mind.
Another solution is then to replace the abstract type with a type parameter (though it is more verbose):

```
trait A[B] {
  def foo(b: B)
}

trait C[B, D <: A[B]] {
  val d: D
  def createB(): B
  def bar() {
    d.foo(createB)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** *given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983501/614394) I'm not sure whether this should be considered a bug or not*

This is a bug: [SI-4377](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4377). An explicit type ascription yields

```
trait C[D <: A] {
  val d: D
  def createB(): D#B
  def bar() {
    (d:D).foo(createB) 
      // [error]  found   : D#B
      // [error]  required: _3.B where val _3: D
  }
}
```

which looks like the implementation leaking. There's a workaround which involves casting to an intersection type (dangerous, casting is wrong etc; see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513265/614394))

```
trait A {
  type B
  def foo(b: B)
}
case object A {
  type is[A0 <: A] = A0 {
    type B = A0#B
  }
  def is[A0 <: A](a: A0): is[A0] = a.asInstanceOf[is[A0]]
}

trait C[D <: A] {
  val d: D
  def createB(): D#B
  def bar() {
    A.is(d).foo(createB) // use it here!
  }
}
```