# Why scala does not unify this type lambda with underlying type?

Tags: scala, existential-type

```
trait A {
  type T
  def test(t: T): Unit
}

case class B[S <: A](a: S, t : S#T) {
  def test() = a.test(t) // Error: type mismatch;
    // found   : B.this.t.type (with underlying type S#T)
    // required: B.this.a.T
}
```

Am I wrong to expect the above to compile? Can my code be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiler has not sufficient evidence that `S#T` can be used as argument for `test` in concrete instance.

Consider this hypotecical example for weakened scala compiler

```
trait A2 extends A{
  type T <: AnyRef
}

class A3 extends A2{
  override type T = Integer

  def test(t: Integer): Unit = println(t * 2)
}
```

So `B[A2]` should accept instance of `A3` along with anything that is `<: AnyRef` while `A3` needs exactly `Integer` for its own `test` implementation

You can catch concrete type in the definition of `B`, to make sure what type will be used

```
case class B[S <: A, ST](a: S {type T = ST}, t: ST) {
  def test() = a.test(t) 
}
```

Comment: But `B[A2](new A3(), "")` does not compile though... did you mean that it would with my code?

Otherwise your solution is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ha, a clever trick! I didn't know one can use type parameter on the right hand sight in the refinement.

Comment: @JbGi Yes I thought a lot how to demonstrate this with an actually compiling example, but scala compiler is pretty restrictive here. So let keep this just an imaginary example for imaginary scala-like compiler, that could compile original source

Comment: forcing the OP version to compile through casting doesn't help in making `B[A2](new A3(), "")` compile, as `String` doesn't conform to `A2#T`.

Answer (score 2):

I could come up with encodings (removed the type parameters for simplification):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def test0(a: A)(t : a.T) = a.test(t) 

abstract class B{
  val a: A
  val t: a.T
  def test = a.test(t)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

test0: (a: A)(t: a.T)Unit
defined class B
```

This on the other hand didn't work with case classes arguments (nor classes' for that matter).

One of the reasons your encoding wouldn't work:

```
scala> def test1(a: A)(t : A#T) = a.test(t) 
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : t.type (with underlying type A#T)
 required: a.T
       def test1(a: A)(t : A#T) = a.test(t)
```

The important part is `required: a.T` (versus `A#T`). The test method in `A` doesn't take any T, it takes T `this.T`, or in other words, the T belonging to one particular instance of A.

Comment: Thanks! that helped me better understand! So `a.T` is what is called a "path-dependant type"?

Comment: Exactly, that's a path-dependent type.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a type projection you can use the dependent type `a.T`:

```
trait A {
  type T
  def test(t: T): Unit
}

case class B[S <: A](a: S)(t : a.T) {
  def test() = a.test(t)
}
```