# Why high order implicits are ignored in some cases?

Tags: scala, implicit

I got a strange compiler error about an implicit that is actually present but could not be found for a reason. So I've build a small test case that reproduces mysterious behaviour.

```
trait Hide {
  type T
}
object HideString extends Hide {
  override type T = String
}
object HideBool extends Hide {
  override type T = Boolean
}
```

Simple type used as unambiguous target for implicit conversions.

```
def id[H <: Hide, C](x : C)(implicit ev : C => H#T) : H#T = ev(x)
def drop[H <: Hide, C](x : C)(implicit ev : C => H#T) : Int = {
  println(ev(x))
  1
}
def idSeq[H <: Hide, C](x : Seq[C])(implicit ev : Seq[C] => Seq[H#T]) : Seq[H#T] = ev(x)
def dropSeq[H <: Hide, C](x : Seq[C])(implicit ev : Seq[C] => Seq[H#T]) : Int = {
  println(ev(x))
  1
}
```

Methods that rely on implicit conversions. It is basically 2x2 matrix. `id` methods returns converted type and `drop` methods use conversion internally and return some constant. Normal methods operates on exact implicitly converted type and `Seq` methods operates on sequences.

```
implicit def exString(x : String) : HideString.type#T = x
implicit def highString[F[_]](x : F[String]) : F[HideString.type#T] = x
```

Above implicit conversions `highString` is defined with higher-order type.

```
val s1 = id("sdf")
val s2 = drop("aero")

val r1 = idSeq(Seq("a", "bc"))
val r2 = dropSeq(Seq("i", "IO"))
```

Trying to actually use conversions brings me an error:

```
ImplicitResolution.scala:98: error: No implicit view available from Seq[String] => Seq[test.implicits.HighReduction.Hide#T].
  val r2 = dropSeq(Seq("i", "IO"))
```

That could be summarized in the following matrix:

```
|        | id   | drop |
|--------+------+------|
| normal | pass | pass |
| seq    | pass | fail |
```

If I use precisely defined implicit conversion for `dropSeq` method it is found normally:

```
implicit def seqBool(x : Seq[Boolean]) : Seq[HideBool.type#T] = x

val a1 = idSeq(Seq(true, false))
val a2 = dropSeq(Seq(false, true))
```

And furthermore if I explicitly specify implicit argument `dropSeq` began to work:

```
val r2i = dropSeq(Seq("i", "IO"))(highString[Seq] _)
```

And that is the strangest thing. `highString` implicit fits all requirements. And it is declared as `implicit`, so it should be found by the compiler. And in case of `idSeq` it is actually found. So, why it is ignored in the `dropSeq` case?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the only difference between `idSeq` and `dropSeq` is the return type: you have hit some corner case in the Scala compiler which is worth signaling to the Scala community.

That said, your idSeq has wrong signature: `H#X` doesn't mean the X type for the specified `H` type, but rather `X` for any instance of H (not the one that has been resolved by the compiler,  see Daniel Sobral explanation here [What does the `#` operator mean in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala))

What you probably want to do is to establish a relation between H and your result type, which is easier if you introduce type aliases to get a more readable signature:

```
object Hide {
  type HideAux[X] = Hide { type T = X}
}
```

You can then re-write your code like this:

```
  def idSeq[B,H <: HideAux[B], C](x : Seq[C])(implicit ev : Seq[C] => Seq[B]) : Seq[B] = ev(x)
  def dropSeq[B,H <: HideAux[B], C](x : Seq[C])(implicit ev : Seq[C] => Seq[B]) : Int = {
    println(ev(x))
    1
  }
```

This code compile, and notice also that if you correctly use generic and typeclasses, you won't need two different methods `id` and `idSeq` because the dynamic behaviour is going to be provided by typeclass itself.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to award you the bounty if you filed an issue for the "corner case in the Scala compiler" that you describe. I assumed this was some corner case, but you still haven't provided enough information for me to know if this is *expected* behavior, or if it's really a bug in the compiler. It would also be nice if you got rid of that dangling `}`...

Comment: Your two functions have same signature except for return type, but you use type inference for r1 and r2 (therefore the return type cannot be used for implicit resolution). If it is possible to resolve the implicit for r1 with the available type information, it is possible to resolve the implicit for r2: given that drop works and dropSeq doesn't, it is likely that the problem is with generic type and type projections.

Comment: Using `-Xlog-implicits` yields some interesting errors.