# Understanding Type Projection

Tags: scala, partial-application, type-constructor, kind-projector

Taken from [typelevel/kind-projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector), what's the distinction between:

```
// partially-applied type named "IntOrA"
type IntOrA[A] = Either[Int, A]
```

and

```
// type projection implementing the same type anonymously (without a name).
({type L[A] = Either[Int, A]})#L
```

?

Are they equivalent?

Comment: What is this `#L` at the end?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov well `#L` accesses the type member that was just created inside

Comment: @Łukasz And what's the use of `#`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `#` is type projection. It allows you to access any path dependent type, which L is and treat it as not being path dependent, i.e. by path dependent types inner types are not equal when accessed with `.`, but are equal when accessed with `#`. See more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala

Comment: Related question [What is a kind projector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39905267/5205022)

Answer (score 4):

They are almost equivalent, as it is said in the comment.

Say you have a class `trait Super[F[_]] {}`, and you want to implement it where `F[x] = Either[Int, x]`
You could write:

```
type IntOrA[A] = Either[Int, A]
class B extends Super[IntOrA] {}
```

But if you want a one liner, you could write:

```
class B extends Super[({type L[A] = Either[Int, A]})#L] {}
```

Or with kind-projector you could write it like:

```
class B extends Super[λ(A => Either[Int, A])] {}
```

or even:

```
class B extends Super[Either[Int, ?]] {}
```

there is no other difference than making it a one line and having this type anonymous.