# Functor Instance for Type Constructor with Two Parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, scalaz, type-constructor, kind-projector

I have a class `Foo` with two parameters, and I am trying to write a Functor instance for Foo with the first parameter fixed, as follows:

```
object Scratchpad {

  trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def fmap[A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]
  }

  case class Foo[X, Y](value: Y)

  implicit def fooInstances[X]: Functor[Foo[X, _]] =
    new Functor[Foo[X, _]] {
      def fmap[A, B](f: A => B): Foo[X, A] => Foo[X, B] =
        foo => Foo[X, B](f(foo.value))
    }
}
```

But the above code fails to compile, generating the following error:

```
Error:(9, 41) Scratchpad.Foo[X, _] takes no type parameters, expected: one
  implicit def fooInstances[X]: Functor[Foo[X, _]] =
```

I know Scalaz does something like this with their `\/` type, but inspection of their source code reveals an odd `?`, which doesn't compile for me:

```
implicit def DisjunctionInstances1[L]: Traverse[L \/ ?] with Monad[L \/ ?] with BindRec[L \/ ?] with Cozip[L \/ ?] with Plus[L \/ ?] with Optional[L \/ ?] with MonadError[L \/ ?, L] =
```

How does the Scalaz `?` work, and how can I write a Functor instance for `Foo`?

Comment: Related question [What is a kind projector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39905267/5205022)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking to partially apply a type-level constructor. Unfortunately, we can't *directly* do that. However, we can still do so indirectly using a little feature called [Structural Types](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/02/introducing-structural-types.html). In order to turn `Foo` from a two-argument type constructor into a one-argument type constructor, we'll define a type synonym inside of an anonymous, structural type.

```
implicit def fooInstances[X]: Functor[({ type T[A] = Foo[X, A] })#T] =
  new Functor[({ type T[A] = Foo[X, A] })#T] {
    // ...
  }
```

The braces `{}` in a type context define an anonymous type that we're exploiting to essentially create a lambda function at the type level. We define an anonymous type with an alias inside of it, then immediately evaluate that alias.

Answer (score 10):

> but inspection of their source code reveals an odd ?, which doesn't
>   compile for me

`?` comes from the [`kind-projector`](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) project, which is a Scala compiler plugin you need to add to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.4")
```

Which prettifies the creation of type lambdas for you:

```
implicit def fooInstances[X]: Functor[Foo[X, ?]] =
  new Functor[Foo[X, ?]] {
    def fmap[A, B](f: A => B): Foo[X, A] => Foo[X, B] =
      foo => Foo[X, B](f(foo.value))
}
```

Remember that we can also use partial type application with type aliases:

```
implicit def fooInstances[X] = {
  type PartiallyAppliedFoo[A] = Foo[X, A]
  new Functor[PartiallyAppliedFoo] {
    override def fmap[A, B](f: (A) => B): (PartiallyAppliedFoo[A]) => PartiallyAppliedFoo[B] = foo => Foo[X, B](f(foo.value))
  }
}
```

### Edit (05/04/2020)

Note the syntax for kind project has changed from `?` to `*` for partially applied types, thus the above example should be:

sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.0")
```

Code:

```
implicit def fooInstances[X]: Functor[Foo[X, *]] =
  new Functor[Foo[X, *]] {
    def fmap[A, B](f: A => B): Foo[X, A] => Foo[X, B] =
      foo => Foo[X, B](f(foo.value))
}
```

Comment: I wish I could checkmark two answers, since you addressed the `?`. I guess that's my fault for asking two questions in one.

Comment: @FriedBrice No problem, as long as you've got your answer that's what's important :)

Comment: Syntax switched from `?` to `*`: https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector/pull/109