# How to use the MonadError with the effect type IO?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to write tests for my tagless algebra that it use the `MonadError`.

Here is tagless algebra with the interpreter:

```
trait DbConnector[F[_]] {
  def read(url: DbUrl, user: DbUser, pw: DbPw): F[DbParams]
}


object DbConnector {

  def apply[F[_]](implicit dc: DbConnector[F]): dc.type = dc

  def impl[F[_] : MonadError[*[_], Throwable]](env: Environment[F])
  : DbConnector[F] =
    new LiveDbConnector[F](env)

}
```

and the test class with `MonadError` instance of `Either`:

```
class DbConnectorSpec extends munit.FunSuite {
  test("Environment variables are not set") {

    val monadError = MonadError[IO[Either[DbError, DbParams]], DbError]
    implicit val badEnv = DbConnector.impl(LiveBadEnvironment())


  }
}
```

the code does not get compiled, because of the error message:

```
cats.effect.IO[Either[io.databaker.db.DbError,io.databaker.db.DbParams]] takes no type parameters, expected: 1
[error]     val monadErr = MonadError[IO[Either[DbError, DbParams]], DbError]
```

The `MonadError` is new to me and that is the first time, I am trying to use it. I have read the concept of the `MonadError` on https://www.scalawithcats.com/dist/scala-with-cats.html.

How to make it run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the type parameter clause of `MonadError`

```
trait MonadError[F[_], E]
```

Note how `F` and `E` are of different shapes (or kinds):

```
F - a type constructor of * -> * kind
E - a proper type of * kind
```

The [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62358854/5205022) between a type constructor and a proper type is like the difference between `List` and `List[Int]`, that is, a type constructor `List` needs a type argument `Int` to *construct* a proper type `List[Int]`.

Now consider the kind of `IO[Either[Throwable,Int]]`

```
scala> :kind -v IO[Either[Throwable, Int]]
cats.effect.IO[Either[Throwable,Int]]'s kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

We see it has the shape of the proper type so it will not fit in place of `F`

```
scala> MonadError[IO[Either[Throwable, Int]], Throwable]
<console>:25: error: cats.effect.IO[Either[Throwable,Int]] takes no type parameters, expected: one
       MonadError[IO[Either[Throwable, Int]], Throwable]
```

Now consider the kind of `IO`

```
scala> :kind -v IO
cats.effect.IO's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```

We see it is a type constructor of `* -> *` shape which matches the shape of `F` type constructor. Therefore we can write

```
scala> MonadError[IO, Throwable]
res2: cats.MonadError[cats.effect.IO,Throwable] = cats.effect.IOLowPriorityInstances$IOEffect@75c81e89
```

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qgvGvp2RRQm0VYLs19LKGQ) are some further examples

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.instances.either._
import cats.instances.try_._
import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Try

MonadError[Future, Throwable]
MonadError[Try, Throwable]
MonadError[IO, Throwable]
MonadError[Either[String, *], String]
MonadError[EitherT[IO, String, *], String]
MonadError[EitherT[Future, String, *], String]
```

Note the `*` in `Either[String, *]` syntax comes from [kind-projector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274120/5205022) and is an alternative to using a type alias to convert, for example, `* -> * -> *` kind into required `* -> *` kind

```
scala> :kind -v Either[String, *]
scala.util.Either[String,?]'s kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> type MyError[+A] = Either[String, A]
defined type alias MyError

scala> :kind -v MyError
MyError's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```