# How do I make sure a function receives the same parameter type as the current object?

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, self-type

```
abstract class A {
  protected[this] type ThisType = this.type
  protected[this] type OtherType = this.type 

  def assign(other: OtherType): ThisType
}

class B extends A {
  def assign(other: OtherType): ThisType = ???
}

class C extends A {
  def assign(other: OtherType): ThisType = ???
}

class D extends C {
  def assign(other: OtherType): ThisType = ???
}
```

How do I make sure the other type received in `assign` of and object of type `B` is also `B`. e.g. how can I write something effectively like:

```
def f1(p1: A, p2: A) = p1.assign(p2)
def f2[T <: A](p1: T, p2: T) = p1.assign(p2)
```

I am getting following errors:

[image: Error at p1]
[image: Error at p2]

NB: Actually `ThisType` and `OtherType` should be the same but I seperated them so I can try out different options.

Comment: You want the type of `p1` and `p2` to be of the implementing class?

Comment: Yes. I want it to be the same implementing class.

Comment: `ThisType` and `OtherType` are meant to be two separate types?

Comment: No they are the same but I have separated them. If `ThisType = B` then `OtherType = B`

Comment: So they can actually be a single type, i.e. `ThisType`?

Comment: Yes. They are single type. Initially I had one type but to try different options I separated them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want can be done using [Type Projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): T = {
  f1(new C, new C)
}

abstract class A {
  type ThisType <: A
  def assign(other: ThisType): ThisType
}

class C extends A {
  override type ThisType = C
  override def assign(other: C): C = ???
}

class D extends C {
  override type ThisType = D
  override def assign(other: D): D = ???
}

def f1[T <: A](p1: T#ThisType, p2: T#ThisType) = p1.assign(p2)
```

Another way can be using [F-bound polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification):

```
abstract class A[T <: A[T]] {
  def assign(other: T): T
}

class C extends A[C] {
  override def assign(other: C): T = ???
}

def f1[T <: A[T]](p1: T, p2: T) = p1.assign(p2)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid  F-bound polymorphism hence Type Projections approach was what I was after. That's why I defined the class like above but providing both makes the answer compete. Thanks for this.

Comment: I have a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809778/how-do-you-use-type-projections-to-p1-and-p2-are-the-same-type-in-p1-assignp2. I actually cannot use signature of `def f1[T <: A](p1: T#ThisType, p2: T#ThisType) = p1.assign(p2)` for my problem (though this is not what I endted asking in this question). I can only have `def run: Unit`