# How to define a certain recursive type in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, types

Suppose I have a type `A`. How can I define a type `B` in scala which is either `Unit` or the tuple `(A, B)`?

I want to model a type `B[A]` which can be

```
(), (A, ()), (A, (A, ())), (A, (A, (A, ()))), (..., (A, (A, (A, ())))).
```

I have seen things like

```
trait B[A] extends (A, B) {}
```

or examples in

[What does the `#` operator mean in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but was not able to work with what I found since the terminating `Unit` possibility is missing.

Thank you.

Comment: `type B[A] = List[A]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a sealed trait (alegbraic data type) to encode the possibility with type safety.

See how the HList from shapeless[1] does this..

```
sealed trait HList
sealed trait HNil extends HList
case object HNil extends HNil
case class ::[+H, +T <: HList](head: H, tail: T) extends HList

@ val xs = 1 :: 2.0 :: "three" :: HNil 
xs: Int :: Double :: String :: HNil = 1 :: 2.0 :: three :: HNil
```

When you say you need it to be either a tuple or a Unit, those are the cases that `extend` the `sealed trait`. Then you can use exhaustive pattern matching on them.

[1] https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Answer (score 6):

How about the following (similar to how `List` is defined):

```
trait NestedTuple[+A]

case class Tup[A](a: A, tail: NestedTuple[A]) extends NestedTuple[A]
case object End extends NestedTuple[Nothing]

val t1: NestedTuple[Int] = End      
t1: NestedTuple[Int] = End

val t2: NestedTuple[Int] = Tup(1, Tup(2, End)) 
t2: NestedTuple[Int] = Tup(1,Tup(2,End))
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a Free Monad. You can take an implementation from `scalaz` library or `cats`.

Comment: I think its more like HList from shapless. I dont see how it has much to do with free.

Comment: @Stephen, actually, it's even the type `List`, since all elements have the same type.