# Specifying inner class argument vs object

Tags: scala

I'd like to accept an argument of an inner class type somewhere, but I'm not sure of how to do this, for example,

```
class Outer(...) {
  class Inner(...) { }
}

object Outer {...}

....

someFunc(arg : Outer.Inner) = {...}
```

but Scala is looking for type Inner in object Outer, not class Outer. so I get "type Inner is not a member of object Outer"

I'd like not to change the definitions of Outer/Inner if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a [path dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types), you'll have to require an instance of type `Outer` to be provided, so you can refer to that instances `Inner` type as well:

```
someFunc(outer: Outer)(inner: outer.Inner) = {...}
```

That, or define an inner function where there is an `Outer` instance in scope.

If you just want an instance of `Inner`, unrelated to the `Outer` instance, then you're looking for [type projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala):

```
someFunc(inner: Outer#Inner) = {...}
```

It isn't too clear from your question which of the two you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exactly you want to achieve:

You need to have an instance of your Outer class in scope to access the type definition of your Inner type:

```
class Outer() {
  class Inner() { }
}

object Outer {

}

val o = new Outer()
def someFunc(arg : o.Inner) = {

}

someFunc(new o.Inner())
```

This is because in Scala inner classes are bound to the outer object and not to the enclosing class ([see here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/115))