# What is this Scala syntax?

Tags: scala, types, path-dependent-type, phantom-types, refinement-type

Take a look at this:

```
/** takes a Spellbook and returns a Spellbook guaranteeing 
  * that all spells have been loaded from the database. */
 def checkIfSpellsLoaded[S <: Spellbook](spellbook :S) :Option[S { type SpellsLoaded }] =
    if (spellbook.spellsLoaded) Some(spellbook.asInstanceOf[S { type SpellsLoaded }])
    else None
 def checkIfOwnerLoaded[S <: Spellbook](spellbook :S) :Option[S { type OwnerLoaded }] =
     if (spellbook.ownerLoaded) Some(spellbook.asInstanceOf[S { type OwnerLoaded }])
     else None
```

What is that { type X } doing as part of a type parameter?? What is going on here?

Comment: Abstract type member https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html used in type refinement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala class members can be `def`, `val` and (relevant for us) `type`

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html

https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html

[Scala: Abstract types vs generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics)

[How to work with abstract type members in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938243/how-to-work-with-abstract-type-members-in-scala)

Type members are used to create path-dependent types

[What is meant by Scala's path-dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-dependent-function.html

If `Spellbook` has type members `SpellsLoaded`, `OwnerLoaded`

```
trait Spellbook {
  type SpellsLoaded
  type OwnerLoaded

  def spellsLoaded: Boolean
  def ownerLoaded: Boolean
}
```

then for `S <: Spellbook` the types `S`, `S { type SpellsLoaded }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded }` are the same

```
type S <: Spellbook

implicitly[(S { type SpellsLoaded }) =:= S] // compiles
implicitly[S =:= (S { type SpellsLoaded })] // compiles
implicitly[(S { type OwnerLoaded }) =:= S]  // compiles
implicitly[S =:= (S { type OwnerLoaded })]  // compiles
```

But if `Spellbook` doesn't have type members `SpellsLoaded`, `OwnerLoaded`

```
trait Spellbook {
  // no SpellsLoaded, OwnerLoaded

  def spellsLoaded: Boolean
  def ownerLoaded: Boolean
}
```

then the refined types `S { type SpellsLoaded }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded }` are just subtypes of `S` (having those type members)

```
implicitly[(S { type SpellsLoaded }) <:< S] // compiles
// implicitly[S <:< (S { type SpellsLoaded })] // doesn't compile
implicitly[(S { type OwnerLoaded }) <:< S] // compiles
// implicitly[S <:< (S { type OwnerLoaded })] // doesn't compile
```

and the refined types `S { type SpellsLoaded = ... }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded = ... }` in their turn are subtypes of the former refined types

```
implicitly[(S {type SpellsLoaded = String}) <:< (S {type SpellsLoaded})] // compiles
// implicitly[(S {type SpellsLoaded}) <:< (S {type SpellsLoaded = String})] // doesn't compile
implicitly[(S {type OwnerLoaded = Int}) <:< (S {type OwnerLoaded})] // compiles
// implicitly[(S {type OwnerLoaded}) <:< (S {type OwnerLoaded = Int})] // doesn't compile
```

`S { type SpellsLoaded }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded }` are shorthands for `S { type SpellsLoaded >: Nothing <: Any }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded >: Nothing <: Any }` while `S { type SpellsLoaded = SL }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded = OL }` are shorthands for `S { type SpellsLoaded >: SL <: SL }` and `S { type OwnerLoaded >: OL <: OL }`.

Casting `.asInstanceOf[S { type SpellsLoaded }]`, `.asInstanceOf[S { type OwnerLoaded }]` looks like `SpellsLoaded`, `OwnerLoaded` are used as *phantom types*

https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:labelled-generic:type-tagging (5.2 Type tagging and phantom types)

So you seem to encode in types that the methods `checkIfSpellsLoaded`, `checkIfOwnerLoaded` were applied to `S`.

See also

[Confusion about type refinement syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967633/confusion-about-type-refinement-syntax)

[What is a difference between refinement type and anonymous subclass in Scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149674/what-is-a-difference-between-refinement-type-and-anonymous-subclass-in-scala-3)