# Scala nested implicit type parameters

Tags: scala, context-bound

Can you please explain the type `T` in this method definition? This is from gatling. I know that colon is for context bound values. here I see them nested. What is `#` for?

```
implicit def stringToExpression[T: TypeCaster: Types[NonValidable]#DoesNotContain: ClassTag](string: String): Expression[T] = string.el
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method signature is translated to:

```
implicit def stringToExpression(string: String)(implicit t: TyperCaster[T], nv: Types[NonValidable]#DoesNotContain[T], ct: ClassTag[T]) = string.el
```

`#` in this context is a [Type Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala) used to refer to the inner `DoesNotContain[T]` class.