# Path-dependency and inner classes

Tags: scala, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

Following sample code fails to compile with the error listed below.

```
class Outer {
  class Inner

  val instance: Inner = new Inner

  def verify(pd: Inner): Boolean = pd == instance
}

class UseOuter(val pdp: Outer) {
  def foo: pdp.Inner = pdp.instance
}

class UseCase {
  val pdp = new Outer
  val user = new UseOuter(pdp)

  val i = user.foo

  pdp.verify(i)
}
```

Error:

```
test.sc:19: type mismatch;
 found   : UseCase.this.user.pdp.Inner
 required: UseCase.this.pdp.Inner
  pdp.verify(i)
             ^
Compilation Failed
```

I'm not entirely sure but reading [Inner Classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/inner-classes.html) suggests that it's the intended behaviour? Specifically the following sentence:

> As opposed to Java-like languages where such inner classes are members
>   of the enclosing class, in Scala such inner classes are bound to the
>   outer object.

If that's the case and this is indeed the desired behaviour, is there a way to encode this requirement in Scala?

There are a few similar questions but they all concern inner types, and not classes and the proposed solutions will not apply.

Comment: Actually the very documentation you reference has an answer at the end where Scala is compared to Java and `Graph.Node` is compared to `Graph#Node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use [type projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala):

```
class Outer {
  class Inner

  val instance: Inner = new Inner

//  def verify(pd: Inner): Boolean = pd == instance
  def verify(pd: Outer#Inner): Boolean = pd == instance
}

class UseOuter(val pdp: Outer) {
//  def foo: pdp.Inner = pdp.instance
  def foo: Outer#Inner = pdp.instance
}

class UseCase {
  val pdp: Outer = new Outer
  val user: UseOuter = new UseOuter(pdp)

//  val i: user.pdp.Inner = user.foo
  val i: Outer#Inner = user.foo

  pdp.verify(i)
}
```

Comment: I think the technically you don't need to change the type of `instance` to `Outer#Inner`, only in the `foo` and `verify`. Cast from `outerInstance.Inner` to `Outer#Inner` is always safe and automatic.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that maintains the safety of path-dependent types for those times when you want it. First, modify `UseOuter` to take the type of `pdp` as a type parameter:

```
class UseOuter[O <: Outer](val pdp: O) {
  def foo: pdp.Inner = pdp.instance
}
```

Then, when you instantiate `UseOuter`, *explicitly* pass `pdp.type` as the type parameter:

```
val user = new UseOuter[pdp.type](pdp)
```

This allows the compiler to remember that the `pdp` in `UseOuter` is the same `pdp` in `UseCase`, so the types match up correctly.

Comment: You can improve the ergonomics of this a little by defining `pdp` as `object pdp extends Outer`, in which case `new UseOuter(pdp)` will infer the singleton type without needing the explicit type argument.