# scala simple example of proper subtyping

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and trying to understand the right way to think about subtypes, so here's a simple example.

Let's say I want to make a function `truncation()` that takes a number and rounds it down to a few decimals places and returns the result. I might go about this as,

```
def truncation(number:Double, level:Int)={
  math.floor(number * math.pow(10,level)) / math.pow(10,level)
}

truncation(1.2345, 2)
res0: Double = 1.23
```

But I probably also want this function to work with other numeric types besides `Double`,  such as `Float`.

So how should I think about generalizing this function to work well with multiple types?

I'm thinking I should be using generic types such as

```
def truncation [A](number:A, level:Int):A={
  math.floor(number * math.pow(10,level)) / math.pow(10,level)
}
```

but this doesn't compile. 
In the case of just two types, I see that the `Either` type [is a good option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611012/accept-multiple-types-for-a-parameter-in-scala). But in the more general case,maybe I'll want to be able to handle `Ints` as well, and have different implementations that `match` on the type of the input object.

What's the best way to be thinking about this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This sounds like a situation for Scala Type Classes.  You should search for that and read tutorials on it.

Comment: Something like this link: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

Comment: thanks @cmbaxter! I actually just stumbled on this one. I'll read through this and come up with an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a generic that you want to constrain to numeric types, you can use `Numeric`:

```
def truncation[T](number: T, level:Int)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
    import math._
    val doubleValue = n.toDouble(number)
    floor(doubleValue * pow(10,level)) / pow(10,level)
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
def truncation[T : Numeric](number: T, level:Int) = {
    import math._
    val doubleValue = implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(number)
    floor(doubleValue * pow(10,level)) / pow(10,level)
}
```

These will work for `Ints`, `Doubles`, `Floats`, and other numeric types.

The first example uses an implicit parameter, which you can read about [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html).  The second version uses a context bound, which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala) together with the `implicitly` operator, which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/what-is-the-scala-identifier-implicitly). Finally, read the documentation of `Numeric` [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) to see all the available methods.

Note that the versions above both return `Double`.  If you want them to return `T` (whatever the input type is), you can try:

```
def truncation[T : Numeric](number: T, level:Int): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]] match {
    case n:Fractional[T] =>
        val tenPow = n.fromInt(math.pow(10, level).toInt)
        n.div(n.fromInt(n.toInt(n.times(number, tenPow))), tenPow)
    case n:Integral[T] => number
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was just reading about `Numeric` and was unsure how to utilize it. So we have to convert with `toDouble` so that `doubleValue` and the result of `pow` are of the same type for `*`?

Comment: Right.  `math.pow` returns `Double`, so we need a `Double` to multiply it with.  Furthermore, `floor` expects a double, so the input needs to be a `double` as well.