# How to say that a type parameter must have one supertype of alternative supertypes?

Tags: scala

One can say a type parameter T must have a specific supertype S_1:

```
class Test[T <: S_1]
```

Is there a way to say, that a type parameter must have at least one supertype of multiple supertype alternatives ?
Something like (pseudocode) :

```
class Test[T <: S_1 || S_2]
```

Or: Is this not possible, because such a construction makes no sense and would be a hint of a design mistake in the code ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how that might be used?  Are you thinking of a case in which objects of type parameter `T` will only use a method that happens to have the same signature in the unrelated types `S_1` and `S_2`?

Comment: What you are looking for is a *union type*; see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3508077/770361

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** The intuitive solution is to make `S_1` and `S_2` share a common trait that represents the set of abilities you require for your type parameter `T`. Use that trait as the upper bound for `T`.

More possibilities:

- If `S_1` and `S_2` are unrelated in nature and your requirement for the type `T` is that it has certain members (that both `S_1` and `S_2` happen to implement), you can use a [structural type](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#structural_types) to formulate that (the concept behind is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)).
- If for some reason you really require `T` to be a subclass of `S_1` or `S_2`, and you can't change those types, you can use implicits to convert both of these to a newly introduced internal type `S_1_or_2`, which you can then use as an upper bound for your `T`.

Answer (score 3):

Let me expand on [Niklas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916657/niklas-b) second alternative. Implicit parameters can be used to *prove something* about the type, so this seems like just the thing. It would go like this:

```
class ThingIWantToProve[T]
object ThingIWantToProve {
  // Here I define the proofs I need
  implicit def s1IsProvable: ThingIWantToProve[S_1] = new ThingIWantToProve[S_1]
  implicit def s2IsProvable: ThingIWantToProve[S_2] = new ThingIWantToProve[S_2]
}
class Test[T : ThingIWantToProve] // here I use a context bound
```