# Overloading with different evidence parameters under type erasure

Tags: scala, overloading, type-erasure

Given type erasure, what is the most efficient and elegant way to solve the following overloading definition:

```
trait Signal

trait Step[T] {
  def ar(implicit ev: T <:< Boolean): Signal
  def ar(implicit ev: T <:< Float  ): Signal
}
```

without using different names for `Boolean` and `Float` parametrisation? Ideally it would be `T <:< Boolean union Float` but that does not exist... Can I do without an extra implicit indirection?

Comment: The `Boolean union Float` would not help in the actual implementation, though, because that would need to figure out how to convert `T` into another type (e.g. `Float`), thus requiring overloading.

Comment: See [Does Scala have “type disjunction” (union types)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra indirection would be this:

```
object Step {
  sealed trait SignalSource[T] { def toFloat(t: T): Float }
  implicit object BooleanSource extends SignalSource[Boolean] {
    def toFloat(t: Boolean) = if (t) 1f else 0f
  }
  implicit object FloatSource extends SignalSource[Float] {
    def toFloat(t: Float) = t
  }
}
trait Step[T] {
  def ar(implicit ev: Step.SignalSource[T]) : Signal
}
```

Comment: Someone has called this [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/)