# Scala implicit Any wrapper

Tags: scala, types, implicit-conversion, implicit

I am trying to write a wrapper for values for a simple database that I am writing. Currently, I have a class Value that takes a type that is a subtype of ordered (this is important because I will do comparisons on the values). I have implicit wrappers for type Int, Double, String, Boolean, and Date. My problem is, when I try to wrap something of type Any in a Value I receive an error.

Here is my Value class:

```
case class Value[A <% Ordered[A]](value: A) extends Ordered[Value[A]] {

  def matches(otherType: A): Boolean = {
    if(value.getClass == otherType.getClass)
      true
    else false
  }

  override def toString() = {
    value.toString
  }

  def compare(other: Value[A]) = value compare other.value
}

object Value {
  implicit def intVal(some: Int) = new Value[Int](some) {
    def compare(other: Int): Int = value compare other
  }
  implicit def doubleVal(some: Double) = new Value[Double](some) {
    def compare(other: Double): Int = value compare other
  }
  implicit def stringVal(some: String) = new Value[String](some) {
    def compare(other: String): Int = value compare other
  }
  implicit def boolVal(some: Boolean) = new Value[Boolean](some) {
    def compare(other: Boolean): Int = value compare other
  }
  implicit def dateVal(some: Date) = new Value[Date](some) {
    def compare(other: Date): Int = value.compareTo(other)

    override def toString() = {
      var formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
      formatter.format(value)
    }
  }
//  implicit def anyVal(some: Any) = new Value[Any](some){
//    def compare(other: Any) = {
//      
//    }
//  }

  var x = new Value(0)
}
```

From another class I have a List[Any] which I want to wrap as a value (I know the Any is one of the correct types). Unfortunately I have no way of wrapping the Any in a value because it is not of type Ordred.

Also, my problem would be solved if I could use a generic Value as a type parameter but I have the problem:

I know it would make more sense to just put Values in the parameter but when I parse values into my program I have no way of resolving the Type

For instance I would like to do:

```
def integer: Parser[Value] = """\d+""".r ^^ {x => Value(augmentString(x).toInt)}
```

but, it complains that Parser[Value] needs a type.
This isnt a problem because I can make the type [Value[Int]] but, when I have a combiner method like this:

```
def value: Parser[Value[Something]] =  integer ||| real | date
```

or

```
def getSome(some: Value[Something])
```

I dont have a generic Value that encompasses all of the five possible types.

Is there a better solution to what I am trying?

Answer (score 0):

To make `def value: Parser[Value[Something]] =  integer ||| real | date` work you would really need something like..

```
trait Value
case class StringValue(s: String) extends Value
case class IntValue(i: Int) extends Value
case class DateValue(d: Date) extends Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use one of the ways you can encode disjoint union types in scala (see: [Does Scala have “type disjunction” (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types) )

For instance, if you use the ["stuttering or"](http://cleverlytitled.blogspot.it/2009/03/disjoint-bounded-views-redux.html) approach you could define:

```
case class Value[A <% Ordered[A] <% String or Int or Double or Boolean](value: A) extends Ordered[Value[A]] {

  def matches(otherType: A): Boolean = {
    if(value.getClass == otherType.getClass)
      true
    else false
  }

  override def toString() = {
    value.toString
  }

  def compare(other: Value[A]) = value compare other.value
}
```

and then you could have:

```
def integer[T <% Value[T]] = """\d+""".r ^^ {x => Value(augmentString(x).toInt)}
```