# Replacement for specialization of method parameters in subclasses

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I would like to create a framework where users are able to subclass a base class, `Node` which is able to produce a message (here an integer) based on the current instance state, and the properties of another instance (the parameter n). The users should be able to specialize the method `getMessage` to produce different messages based on the class of the current instance and *the class of the parameter n*, as shown in the code below.

The function `importantAlgorithm` uses messages generated by these nodes to compute the final results.

```
// Classes defined by the framework //
abstract class Node {
    def getMessage(n: Node) : Int
}

def importantAlgorithm(lstNodes1: List[_ <: Node], lstNodes2: List[_ <: Node]) = {

    val results = lstNodes1.zip(lstNodes2).map({case (n1, n2) =>
        // I would like to get the proper message *BASED ON
        // THE TYPE OF N1 and N2*
        val message = n1.getMessage(n2)
        // Do some work with the message
        //...
        //...
        })
    //...
}

// Classes defined by framework users //
class ItemNode(val p: Int) extends Node {
    override def getMessage(n: UserNode) = {
        // Compute message based on this ItemNode member variables
        // and n (instance of UserNode) member variables
    }
    override def getMessage(n: ItemNode) = {
        // Compute message based on this ItemNode member variables
        // and n (instance of UserNode) member variables
        // The algorithm is different from the algorithm
        // used in the previous method
    }
}

class UserNode extends Node {
    override def getMessage(n: OtherNode) = {
        // Compute message. Same idea as above
    }
}

class OtherNode extends Node { 
    override def getMessage(n: UserNode) = {
        // Compute message. Same idea as above
    }
}

// The user should be able to use the framework this way
importantAlgorithm(List(new UserNode(), new ItemNode(236), new OtherNode(),
   List(new OtherNode(), new ItemNode(542), new UserNode()))
```

Of course, Scala does not allow to specialize a parameter of a method in a subclass and the above code does not compile. I could use `isInstanceOf[]` or RTTI but I have a feeling that I am not thinking properly and not designing my framework properly. **How could I replace the mechanism described in the code sample above by a simpler and cleaner solution ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this suffice? (It compiles...)

```
/* Classes defined by the framework */
abstract class Node {
    def getMessage(n: Node): Int
}

def importantAlgorithm(lstNodes1: List[Node], lstNodes2: List[Node]) {
  lstNodes1.zip(lstNodes2).map {
    case (n1, n2) =>
      // I would like to get the proper message *BASED ON
      // THE TYPE OF N1 and N2*
      val message = n1.getMessage(n2)
  }
}

/* Classes defined by framework users */
class   ItemNode(val p: Int)
extends Node
{
  def getMessage(n: Node): Int =
    n match {
    // Compute message based on this ItemNode member variables
    // and n (instance of UserNode) member variables
      case un: UserNode => 0
      case in: ItemNode => 1
      case xn: Node     => -1
  }
}

class   UserNode
extends Node
{
  def getMessage(n: Node): Int =
    n match {
      case on: OtherNode => 23
      case xn: Node     => -1
    }
}

class   OtherNode
extends Node
{
  def getMessage(n: Node): Int =
    n match {
      case xn: Node => 514
    }
}

// The user should be able to use the framework this way
importantAlgorithm(List(new UserNode(),
                        new ItemNode(236),
                        new OtherNode()),
                   List(new OtherNode(),
                        new ItemNode(542),
                        new UserNode()))
```

Comment: Yes, the code sample you posted solves my issue but I wanted to see if it was possible to design a "pure" object-oriented solution (i.e. without using pattern matching, isInstance or RTTI). However, I don't think this is feasible since the algorithm to be used to generate messages is based on the class of the first node *and* on the class of the second node.

Comment: @Xion345: You could look into the double-dispatch pattern. It's a way of simulating multi-methods in a single-dispatch OO language like Java or Scala. I have a vague hunch it might work for this case.

Comment: Thank you, *double dispatch* is the mechanism I was looking for (I did not know the keyword). I know have to figure out if it is better to use the associated pattern or to use a pattern-matching based solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need is something like

```
trait Node {
  type AppropriateSender <: Node
  def getMessage(n: AppropriateSender): Int
}

class UserNode extends Node {
  type AppropriateSender = OtherNode
  def getMessage(n: OtherNode) = ???
}

...
```

However, there are some problems caused by type erasure so that you cannot check the compatibility of your `n1` and `n2` (maybe type tags?), but at least you can implement your staff in a clean way now. Another issue is how you deal with the fact that some node types have more than 1 appropriate sender type (which might be solved by an implementation of [raw union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types)).

Comment: Yes, the solution you suggested is the solution of the book _Programming in Scala_ Chapter 18.3, Abstract types. However, my big issue is how to deal with multiple `getMessage` methods taking different `Node` types.

Comment: @Xion345 See the link I provided at the end of the answer, which is a very intelligent trick to implement an unboxed union type (while `Either[A,B]` provided by scala is boxed). Then you can have something like `type AppropriateSender = OtherNode or UserNode`, such that `OtherNode <:< AppropriateSender <:< Node`, which should be exactly what you want if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Xion345 Oh that specific answer I am pointing to is not the accepted one (but the one with nearly same number of votes!). You can also read this article directly: http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/

Comment: I just read the stackoverflow question. Actually, I think that pattern matching is sufficient in my case. I could have a `createMessage(n1: Node, n2: Node)` which computes the correct message based on the type of n1 and n2. Thank you very much for your help.