# Type bound for two unrelated types

Tags: scala

Is it possible to have a restriction on two unrelated types in Scala?
For example,

```
trait A
trait B
def m(T <: A or B) ????
```

Thanks

Comment: You can hack around it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `A` and `B` is totally unrelated (for example, no common method that you need, otherwise you could just use structure type), it means when you use it as method parameter, you still need what type it actually it is in order to use them.

In this case, [Either[A, B]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either) is exactly what you need. It denotes that an object must be one of A or B, and you could use pattern matching or other method in Either class to check them.

For example:

```
class MyClassA { 
  def methodA() = println("I'm A")
}

class MyClassB {
  def methodB() = println("I'm B")
}

def m(a: Either[MyClassA, MyClassB]) {
   a match {
     case Left(a) => a.methodA()
     case Right(b) => b.methodB()
   }
}

m(Left(new MyClassA))  // OK
m(Right(new MyClassB)) // OK
m(Left(new MyClassB))  // Failed, a Left must be a MyClassB instance
```

You may interested in this [article](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/02/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-7-the-either-type.html), which explains what is Either very clearly.

Comment: Minor point; the last line is the same as the third last line - perhaps you meant `m(Left(new MyClassB))` or `m(Right(new MyClassA))`. Also, for conciseness, in the body of `m`, you can use `a.fold(a => a.methodA(), b => b.methodB())`, or even `a.fold(_.methodA(), _.methodB())`

Comment: @KristianDomagala ya, I got a typo there. Thanks. :)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6312508/217959) on the question linked to by @om-nom-nom. Miles Sabin has has a [blog post](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) demonstrating *unboxed* union types -- which drops the Either wrapper object entirely.