# Write Ceylon like union type in Scala, using an alias for Either

Tags: scala, types

With the release of Ceylon 1.0 some people are discussing the usefulness of union types. I was wondering how succinct you could write the following code:

```
String test(String | Integer x) {
  if (x is String) {
     return "found string";
  } else if (x is Integer) {
     return "found int";
  }
  return "why is this line needed?";
}

print(test("foo bar"));  // generates 'timeout'... well, whatever
```

...in Scala? My idea was like this:

```
type | [+A, +B] = Either[A, B]

object is {
  def unapply[A](or: Or[A]): Option[A] = or.toOption

  object Or {
    implicit def left[A](either: Either[A, Any]): Or[A] = new Or[A] {
      def toOption = either.left.toOption
    }
    implicit def right[A](either: Either[Any, A]): Or[A] = new Or[A] {
      def toOption = either.right.toOption
    }
  }
  sealed trait Or[A] { def toOption: Option[A] }
}

def test(x: String | Int) = x match {
  case is[String](s) => "found string"   // doesn't compile
  case is[Int   ](i) => "found int"
}
```

But the pattern extractor doesn't compile. Any ideas?

I know [that a similar question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types) with some working answers, but I specifically wonder whether one can use a type alias for `Either` and extractors, or not. Even if one defines a new type class other than `Either`, the solution should allow for an *exhaustive* pattern match.

Comment: http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/

Comment: @AlexIv yes, that is also included in the linked question. The problem with the final definition of `size` is that the pattern matcher has no clue about the types. You can leave away for example the `case s: String` case without warning. You can add a useless case like `case b: Boolean` without error.

Comment: As I understand, type parameters aren't allowed in unapply https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-884

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko ok, thanks! In my second attempt (below as an "answer"), I have a pattern which doesn't use type application. Perhaps this is a better starting point for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, Dotty has union types, so the example would be

```
def test(x: String | Int): String = x match {
  case _: String => "found string"
  case _: Int    => "found int"
}

println(test("foo bar"))
```

([Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DEr5Z7UrTeKIiGZTjtR63A))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second attempt, in case it helps. It fails with implicit resolution:

```
trait OrLike {
  type A
  type B

  def left : Option[A]
  def right: Option[B]
}

object | {
  implicit def left[A, B](value: A): | [A, B] = new | [A, B] {
    def left  = Some(value)
    def right = None
  }

  implicit def right[A, B](value: B): | [A, B] = new | [A, B] {
    def left  = None
    def right = Some(value)
  }
}
sealed trait | [A1, B1] extends OrLike {
  type A = A1
  type B = B1
}
```

```
object is {
  def unapply[A](or: OrLike)(implicit ev: Or[A]): Option[A] = ev.toOption

  object Or {
    implicit def left[A1](peer: OrLike { type A = A1 }): Or[A1] = new Or[A1] {
      def toOption = peer.left
    }
    implicit def right[B1](peer: OrLike { type B = B1 }): Or[B1] = new Or[B1] {
      def toOption = peer.right
    }
  }
  sealed trait Or[A] { def toOption: Option[A] }
}

def test(x: String | Int) = x match {
  case s is String => "found string"  // no evidence of `Or[A]`
  case i is Int    => "found int"
}

test("foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt. Without generic extractors. I'll try to think how to get it later.

```
sealed trait | [+A, +B]

case class Left[+A](left: A) extends |[A, Nothing]

case class Right[+B](right: B) extends |[Nothing, B]

implicit def toLeft[A, B](a: A): |[A, B] = Left(a)
implicit def toRight[A, B](b: B): |[A, B] = Right(b)

object IsString {
    def unapply(x: |[_, _]): Option[String] = {
        x match {
            case Left(s: String) => Some(s)
            case Right(s: String) => Some(s)
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}

object IsInt {
    def unapply(x: |[_, _]): Option[Int] = {
        x match {
            case Left(i: Int) => Some(i)
            case Right(i: Int) => Some(i)
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}

def test(x: String | Int) = x match {
  case IsString(s) => s"found string: $s"
  case IsInt(i)    => s"found int: $i"
}

println(test(10))
println(test("str"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a more-or-less working implementation of Miles Sabin's C-H idea (linked above).  Not sure if this directly addresses your question, but maybe this is useful food for thought.

The source code is [in this project on GitHub](https://github.com/GenslerAppsPod/scalavro/blob/master/util/src/main/scala/com/gensler/scalavro/util/union.scala).

Here are a quick usage example:

```
type ISB = union [Int] #or [String] #or [Boolean]

def unionFunction[T: prove [ISB] #containsType](t: T) {}

unionFunction(55)
unionFunction("hello")
unionFunction(false)
// unionFunction(math.Pi) // fails to compile (correct behavior)
```

Also provided is a class for boxing these types, because that's often handy:

```
val wrapped = new Union[union [Int] #or [String]]

wrapped.contains[Int] // true
wrapped.contains[String] // true
wrapped.contains[Double] // false

wrapped assign 55
wrapped.value[Int] // Some(55)
wrapped.value[String] // None

wrapped assign "hi, union!"
wrapped.value[String] // Some("hi, union!")
wrapped.value[Int] // None

def unionFunction[T: wrapped.containsType] {}
unionFunction[Int] // compiles :)
unionFunction[String] // compiles :)
```

One more interesting thing is that the API allows union types to be build up one member type at a time, as follows:

```
val unary = new Union[union [Int] #apply]
val binary = new Union[unary.underlying #or [String]]
val ternary = new Union[binary.underlying #or [Float]]
ternary.typeMembers // Seq(typeOf[Int], typeOf[String], typeOf[Float])
```