# Parametric type T in 2 possible states

Tags: scala, generics

Suppose we have a method

```
def foo[T](param: T): Array[String] = {
  //preform smth
}
```

How can we assure type T to be in 2 or more than one possible variants. For example in my particular case I want T to be `String` or my custom type `Bar`

Comment: If you want to be strict about the type of T is there a reason you just aren't overloading foo to support the types you want?

Comment: actually foo calls such overloaded methods passing param as argument, but except that it does another boilerprate which I don't want to be duplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See ["does Scala have type disjunction (union types)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types) and in particular [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312508/402428). This technique allows you to write

```
def size[T : (Int |∨| String)#λ](t : T) = t match {
  case i : Int => i
  case s : String => s.length
}
```

Comment: That's pretty clever, but I shudder at the thought of putting unicode operators (∨, U+2228) into a codebase :)

Comment: a question regarding that first link(define a sealed class and 2 implicit objects): if for example in my method I want to call overloaded version of some other method which overloaded versions take as an argument these 2 possible types. Why that can't be attained? Compiler knows about possible variants of T, so why it complains when I use T in such senario?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `sealed trait` and make both/all types inherit from that `sealed trait`. Of course this only works for types you control, so it doesn't work for `String`. Also, all types must be defined in the same file as the sealed trait.

Here is an example:

```
sealed trait Tr
class Bar extends Tr
class Baz extends Tr

object Test {
  def foo(t: Tr): Array[String] = t match {
    case bar: Bar => Array("It's a bar")
    case baz: Baz => Array("It's a baz")
  }
}
```