# Set the "double" restriction for a generic parameter

Tags: scala

I have 3 classes:

```
abstract class Abs1 { ... }
abstract class Abs2 { ... }

class MyClass[T <: /*Abs1 or Abs2*/] { ... }
```

Is there any way specify that `T` must be a child of `Abs1` **or** `Abs2`?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no.

What would that mean for an object of type `T`? What method would you be able to call, since you do not know whether it has any methods exposed in `Abs1` (since it might be a type derived from `Abs2`) or any methods exposed in `Abs2` (since it might be a type derived from `Abs1`). You could only used methods defined for `Any`, or any other common parent of `Abs1` and `Abs2` if they have some.

In this case, you might as well accept this super type directly, and manipulate `Any` (or a common parent type of `Abs1` and `Abs2`) objects in your methods rather than objects of type `T`. Or you could not put any constraint on `T`: that would give you a generic class that you can instantiate with any specific type, but you would not know anything about this type either except that it derives from `Any`.