# Scala: Is it possible to enforce a type parameter to one of two types?

Tags: scala

In the following statement, type parameter `A` must be a subclass of `AnotherClass`:

```
trait MyClass[A <: AnotherClass] { ... }
```

What if type parameter `A` must be either a type or another? For instance, I need to specify a type parameter that must be either `String` or `Option[String]`.

I don't know if this is actually possible... maybe there are some other technics to deal with such a problem.

Comment: What's the actual use case for handling the `String` and `Option[String]` ?

Comment: I need to define a trait like this: `trait Entity[T] { def id: T; def id_=(v: T): Unit }` where `T` is `Option[String]` for modifiable entities or `String` for unmodifiable entities.

Comment: You can introduce your own type with String/Option[String] semantics

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define "type disjunction" (union types)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types)

Comment: Some implementation of the idea in an old blog: http://cleverlytitled.blogspot.com/2009/03/so-i-read-both-jim-mcbeath-and-michids.html

Comment: Use a disjunction type like `Either`, or any type for whose an instance of appropriate typeclass is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Either` and implicit conversions to get something (in my opinion) close to what you want

```
trait Entity[T] {
  def id: Either[T, Option[T]]
  def id_=(v: Either[T, Option[T]]): Unit
}

object Entity {
  implicit def toLeftEither[T](t: T): Either[T, Option[T]] = Left(t)
  implicit def toRightEither[T](t: Option[T]): Either[T, Option[T]] = Right(t)

  implicit def fromLeftEither[T](e: Either[T, Option[T]]): T = e.left.get
  implicit def frommRightEither[T](e: Either[T, Option[T]]): Option[T] = e.right.get
}
```

Now usage:

```
import Entity._

class E[T] extends Entity[T] {
  private[this] var _id: Either[T, Option[T]] = Right(Option.empty[T])
  def id =  _id
  def id_=(v: Either[T, Option[T]]): Unit = {_id = v}
}

val e = new E[String]
e.id = "1"

val a = e.id // a is of type Either[String, Option[String]]
val b: String = e.id
e.id = Some("1")
val c: Option[String] = e.id

e.id match {
  case Left(id) =>
  case Right(Some(id)) =>
  case _ =>
}
```

But you have to be careful not to mix types, i.e.

```
e.id = "1"
val c: Option[String] = e.id
```

will throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Either.left.value on Right`

Comment: :/ implicit conversions that aren't total give me ulcers

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, how does this work for you?

```
sealed trait Entity[T] { def id: T; def id_=(v: T): Unit }
trait UnmodifiableEntity extends Entity[String]
trait ModifiableEntity extends Entity[Option[String]]
```