# Scala. Why holder class loses type of the value?

Tags: scala, types

In simple example

```
trait Holder[T] {def value: T}

class LongHolder(val value: Long) extends Holder[Long]    
class StringHolder(val value: String) extends Holder[String]

val r1 = List(new LongHolder(1), new StringHolder("a"))    
val h0 = r1(0)    
val h1 = h0.value


scala> r1: List[Holder[_ >: String with Long]] = List(LongHolder@5761bff, StringHolder@d280526)
scala> h0: Holder[_ >: String with Long] = LongHolder@5761bff
scala> h1: Any = 1
```

I can not understand why `h1: Any = 1` in `LongHolder@5761bff`, but not `h1: Long = 1`

without `List` type is not lost

```
val h0 = new LongHolder(1)
val h1 = h0.value

scala> h0: LongHolder = LongHolder@7b2e3720
scala> h1: Long = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens because Scala has no [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types) types like `type T = String | Long`. Your `T` from `List[T]` should have some concrete type, like `String`, `Long` or something, and you can't create list of several types. Every element in the list must have same `T` type, which makes many operations (like `flatMap` or `filter`) to be possible:

```
 scala> val a: (Int, Int, String, String, Int) = parseSomething() // tuple may be seen as List with heterogenous elements
 a: (Int, Int, String, String, Int) = (5, 6, "a", "b", 7)

 scala> val b = a.filter(_ != 6) //how compiler would know that `a._2 == 6` to infer (Int, String, String, Int) ?
 b: (???) = (5, "a", "b", 7)
```

So `T` should be same for all elements. When the compiler sees several parameters that have several types, it's trying to find the nearest common type:

```
def ff[T](a: T, b: T): T = a

trait A
case class A1() extends A
case class A2() extends A 

scala> ff(A1(), A2())
res20: A = A1() //A is the nearest common type
```

Generics are a little bit more interesting. The compiler may infer existential type for them `M[_ >: A1 with A2]`:

```
scala> ff(new LongHolder(1), new StringHolder("a"))
res23: Holder[_ >: String with Long] = LongHolder@a5e201f
```

It means `Holder[T] forSome {type T >: String with Long}`, which means that `Holder` is defined for some `T` (such `T` should *exist* but not necessary for all holders), that `>: String with Long`. Simply saying compiler asks "Hey! We need some `T` that bigger than Int with Long here" (just imagine types as boxes to put something in, and compiler is just a "foreman")

Finally `Any` is smaller (closest) type to fit in (it fits as it can be bigger than `String with Long`), so result is becoming `Any`, as value itself can not be existential in Scala.

P.S. Shapeless [`HList`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) actually does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of a `List` need to be of one type. The compiler will do its best to determine the type of the list if it is not explicitly provided. You have a list that includes a `LongHolder` and a `StringHolder`, so the compiler will try to use the least common type of those types as the type of the list. Since both those types extend `Holder`, it will try to use that as the type.  In order to determine the type to use for the generic parameter of `Holder`, the compiler need to find the least common type of `String` and `Long`, which is the synthetic type `_ with String with Long`. Since no nontrivial types extends both `String` and `Long`, the only type it can use is `Any`, which all types extend.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of [dk14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1809978/dk14) is correct. But if your goal is to save information about types in runtime you can use Scala reflection. I modified example in [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag) a little bit to demonstrate that:

```
def mkList[T : ClassTag](elems: T*) = List[T](elems: _*)

val r1 = mkList(new LongHolder(1L), new StringHolder("a"))
val h0 = r1(0)
h0.value.getClass

scala> h0: Holder[_1] = LongHolder@6618cd9b
scala> res0: Class[?0] = class java.lang.Long
```

Comment: type erasure has nothing to do with this as type becomes "lost" in compile time - not in runtime

Comment: You're right and your explanation is pretty clear about that. I edited my answer and hope it still contains some useful information.