# Scala class/type that can be one from set of other unlinked classes

Tags: scala

I have 3 classes from external lib (A, B, C) both extends Object

How can I define a type of variable that can hold values only of this 3 types (and their subclasses)?
like

```
val myVal: A or B or C (or their sub-classes if this is possible)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala does't provide union types, but you can use `Coproduct`, i.e. a generalization of the `Either` type.

[Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides a nice implementation.

Here's an example straight from the [shapeless's feature overview](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions)

```
scala> type ISB = Int :+: String :+: Boolean :+: CNil
defined type alias ISB

scala> val isb = Coproduct[ISB]("foo")
isb: ISB = foo

scala> isb.select[Int]
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> isb.select[String]
res1: Option[String] = Some(foo)
```

In the example, you define a `Coproduct` type `ISB`, then you can use `select` to extract the type you're looking for. The result of `select` is an `Option` since `isb` may or may not hold an instance of that type.

---

Other approaches, that don't involve libraries, can be found here: [How to define "type disjunction" (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types) and in this excellent blog post by Miles Sabin (author of shapeless): http://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/

Comment: is there any solution for pure scala? (without dependencies)

Comment: @paul_di you don't have a Coproduct directly, but you can use several approaches to mimic a disjunction in vanilla scala. Here's a useful reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types