# Error Handling using extensible disjunction (union) types (as the left side of Either)?

Tags: scala, error-handling, macros, shapeless

I am current brainstorming and researching the best way to do explicit error handling in scala.

Ideal end product:

- Compiler enforce that you have checked all (explicitly stated) errors
- As little boilerplate as possible
- No or little additional runtime cost (which means no parent type of all possible errors from all functions)
- Allows you to be both explicit and implicit in stating

Basically, I want **checked exceptions on steriods**.

Ignoring exception throwing, the typical way to handle this is to use the `Either` type (or `\/` from Scalaz, which I'm using) and have the `left` side to be an ADT containing all possible errors like this:

```
sealed trait Error_parseAndValidate
case class ParseError(msg: String) extends Error_parseAndValidate
case class ValidateError(msg: String) extends Error_parseAndValidate

def parseAndValidate(str: String): Error_parseAndValidate \/ Int = {
    // can return ParseError or ValidateError
}
```

However this gets really tedious if your function call nests multiple levels:

Consider this DB example with the following call stack

`main` -> `getResultWithString` -> `parseAndValidate / fetchResultFromDB`

```
// error type ADT containing expected errors in parseAndValidate
// similarly for other error_* traits
sealed trait Error_parseAndValidate
case class ParseError(msg: String) extends Error_parseAndValidate
case class ValidateError(msg: String) extends Error_parseAndValidate

def parseAndValidate(str: String): Error_parseAndValidate \/ Int = {
    // can return ParseError or ValidateError
}

sealed trait Error_fetchResultFromDB
case class DBError(msg: String) extends Error_fetchResultFromDB

def fetchResultFromDB(lookupId: Int): Error_fetchResultFromDB \/ Result = {
    // can return DBError
}

sealed trait Error_getResultWithString
case class ErrorFromFetchResult(Error_fetchResultFromDB) extends Error_getResultWithString
case class ErrorFromParseValidate(Error_parseAndValidate) extends Error_getReusltWithString

def getResultWithString(input: String): Error_getResultWithString \/ Result = {

}

// we need to 'extract/unwrap' our error type. this is tedious!
def main() = {
    getResultWithString.leftMap {
        case ErrorFromFetchResult(e) => e match {
            case ParseError =>
            case ValidateError =>
        }
        case ErrorFromParseValidate(e) =>  e match {
            case DBERror => 
        }
    }
}
```

Though we achieved correctness, this is tedious especially when you have more than 3-4 level of call stack!

What I am envisioning is an extensible disjunction type which will allow us to 'extend' our errors. It feels like something in `shapelss` might be able to help me achieve this, but have not used it in the past
and I don't think `HList` is the right tool for this situation.

## This is what I have been envisioning:

I am using `|` symbol here to represent disjunction (union) here between two types. The most important thing here is that we no longer need to wrap
and unwrap our errors using ADT -- The Error we finally match on is just a **flat disjunction*.

```
// you can see here we are simply 'joining' the errors from both method calls, 
// instead of wrapping it in a ADT which requires unwrapping
def getResultWithString(input: String): Error_parseAndValidate|Error_fetchResultFromDB \/ Result = {
    for {
        lookupId <- parseAndValidate(input)
        result <- fetchResultFromDB(lookupId)
    } yield result
}

type Error_parseAndValidate = ParseError | ValidateError
def parseAndValidate(input: String): Error_parseAndValidate \/ Int = {
    //returns ParseError or ValidationError
}

type Error_fetchResultFromDB = DBError
def fetchResultFromDB(lookupId: Int): Error_fetchResultFromDB \/ Result = {
    //returns DBError
}

def main() = {
    getResultWithString("bad string").leftMap {
        case ParseError => //...
        case ValidateError => //...
        case DBError => //...
    }
}
```

The answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types) SO question have some solutions, however the solutions are not extensible.

## My question

Is it possible to achieve what I'm envioning in scala?

Comment: If you want to use shapeless, it sounds that you want a [Coproduct](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions), not a HList

Comment: I see it now. But it seems like you can only fetch a particular type (e.g. `isb.select[String]`) but not an exhaustive pattern match. Also it doesn't look to be extensible because at each level you use `CNil` to 'seal' the type :(

Comment: Don't `select`, map over the coproduct with a `Poly`.

Comment: cool. I'll give that a try and report back