# Scala: How to Pattern Match a Union of Parameterized Types

Tags: scala

I am using [Rex Kerr's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types#comment8603587_6883076) of [Miles Sabin's idea](http://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) for implementing unboxed union types in Scala. I have the following class:

```
class Foo[T] {
  trait Contr[-A] {}
  type Union[A,B] = {type Check[Z] = Contr[Contr[Z]] <:< Contr[Contr[A] with Contr[B]]}

  def foo[U: Union[T,Foo[T]]#Check](x:U) = x match {
    case _: Foo[T]       => println("x is a Foo[T]")
    case _: T @unchecked => println("x is a T")
  }
}
```

This allows the following:

```
val aux = new Foo[Int]
aux.foo(aux)   // prints "x is a Foo[T]"
aux.foo(42)    // prints "x is a T"
aux.foo("bar") // does not compile
```

However:

```
val bar = new Foo[Foo[Int]]
bar.foo(bar) // OK: prints "x is a Foo[T]"
bar.foo(aux) // Not OK: prints "x is a Foo[T]"
```

Is there a way to fix this, and maybe also eliminate the `@unchecked`?

**EDIT**
I think the `Union` type, for this particular example, can be simplified to:

```
type Union[Z] = Contr[Contr[Z]] <:< Contr[Contr[T] with Contr[Foo[T]]]
```

and then the foo function can be:

```
def foo[U: Union](x:U) = ...
```

This makes the code simpler. However, the issue remains.

Comment: To remove `@unchecked` use: `case _ => println("x is a T")`

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following, which seems to work, and is closer to my real use case:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Foo[T](z:T)(implicit tt:TypeTag[T], ft:TypeTag[Foo[T]]) {

  trait Contr[-A]
  type Union[Z] = Contr[Contr[Z]] <:< Contr[Contr[T] with Contr[Foo[T]]]

  def foo[U: Union](x:U)(implicit tu:TypeTag[U]):T = tu.tpe match {
    case t if t =:= tt.tpe => x.asInstanceOf[T]
    case t if t =:= ft.tpe => x.asInstanceOf[Foo[T]].z
  }

}
```

Now, the following works well:

```
val aux    = new Foo[Int](42)
val bar    = new Foo[Int](7)
val foobar = new Foo[Foo[Int]](bar)

println(aux.foo(aux))       // 42
println(aux.foo(1))         // 1
println(foobar.foo(aux))    // Foo(42)
println(foobar.foo(foobar)) // Foo(7)
```

I would be nice to get rid of the `x.asInstanceOf`, though.