# Scala: Can an object whose source I do not control be made to extend a trait?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have something like this:

```
object IceCream {
  trait IceCream
  case object ChocolateIceCream extends IceCream
  case object VanillaIceCream   extends IceCream
}
```

whose source code is not mine, and I cannot change. In another program, I would like to reuse this, and make all ice cream flavors be part of another trait. Am I forced to box them, doing something like this?:

```
object ThingsILike{
  import IceCream._

  trait ThingsILike
  case object  Chocolate                   extends ThingsILike
  case class   IceCreamWrapper(x:IceCream) extends ThingsILike
}
```

or does the language provide a way to naturally extend them (like Swift does)?

Comment: You can use the *extend my library* pattern, or type classes, depending on *what* it is you want to do.

Comment: @m-z in the example above, I would like to include `IceCream` objects in the same collection as other `ThingsILike`, and be able to pattern match later on.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types

Comment: @JimN I was experimenting with that a couple of days ago, for another problem, but given the amount of sorcery needed, I would rather box it and pattern match twice. I heard that Dotty does have unboxed union types, so that's something to look forward to. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use implicit to "add" methods to existing classes. You can cause an existing class to be a subclass or pass an isInstanceOf test with a new class or trait.
You can however make your own unapply method to make pattern matching do anything you like.