# How to define a union type that works at runtime?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, union-types

Following on form this excellent set of answers on how to define [union types in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types). I've been using the Miles Sabin definition of Union types, but one questions remains.

How do you work with these if the type isn't know until Runtime? For example:

```
trait inv[-A] {}
type Or[A,B] = {
  type check[X] = (inv[A] with inv[B]) <:< inv[X]
}

case class Foo[A : (Int Or String)#check](a: A)

Foo(1)    // Foo[Int] = Foo(1)
Foo("hi") // Foo[String] = Foo(hi)
Foo(2.0)  // Error!
```

This example works since the parameter `A` is know at compile time, and calling `Foo(1)` is really calling `Foo[Int](1)`. However, what do you do if parameter `A` isn't known until runtime? Maybe you're paring a file that contains the data for `Foo`'s, in which case the type parameter of `Foo` isn't know until you read the data. There's no easy way to set parameter `A` in this case.

The best solutions I've been able to come up with are:

- Pattern Match on the data you've read and then create different `Foo`'s based that type. In my case this isn't feasible because my case-class actually contains dozens of union types, so there'd be hundreds of combinations of types to pattern match.
- Cast the type you've just read to be `(String or Int)`, so you have a single type to pass around, that passes the Type Class constraint when you create `Foo` with it. Then return `Foo[_]` instead. This puts the onus back on the Foo user to work out the type of each field (since they'll appear to be type Any), but at least it defers having to know the type until the field is actually used, in which case a pattern match seems more tractable.

The second solution looks like this:

```
def parseLine: Any // Parses data point, but can be either a String or 
                   // Int, so returns Any.

def mkFoo: Foo[_] = {
  val a = parseLine.asInstanceOf[Int with String]
  Foo(a) // Passes type constraint now
}
```

In practice I've ended up using the second solution, but I'm wondering if there's something better I can do?

Another way to state the problem is: What does it mean to return a Union Type? Functions can only return a single type, and the trickery we use with Miles Sabin union types is only useful for the types you pass in, not for the types you return.

PS. For context, why this is a problem in my case is that I'm generating a set of case-classes from a Json schema file. Json naturally supports union types, so I would like to make my case classes reflect that too. This works great in one direction: users creating case-classes to be serialized out to Json. But gets sticky in the other direction: user's parsing Json files to have a set of populated case classes returned to them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problems with "Pattern Match on the data you've read and then create different Foo's based that type"? If you're discovering the type of data from a file at runtime, there must necessarily exist code that inspects the data and branches based on the result. I don't think that's avoidable.

Comment: The difference is between using that branching to create Foo[X], where X is whatever type you found at runtime. Or using my *hack* to cast X to some type tempory type (A with B) that lets you get past the TypeClass constraint, so therefore you can defer  the branching logic until the user is actually using the fields of Foo (since they'll now appear to be Any to them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "standard" Scala solution to this problem is to use an ordinary discriminated-union type (ie, to forego true union types altogether):

```
sealed trait Foo
case class IntFoo(x: Int) extends Foo
case class StringFoo(x: String) extends Foo
```

This reflects the fact that, as you observe, the particular type of the member is a runtime value; the JVM type-tag of the `Foo` instance provides this runtime value.

Miles Sabin's implementation of union types is very clever, but I'm not sure if it provides any practical benefit, because it only restricts the type of thing that can go into a `Foo`, but provides the user of a `Foo` with no computable version of that restriction, in the way a `match` provides you with a computable version of the `sealed` trait. In general, for a restriction to be useful, it needs two sides: a check that only the right things are put in, and an extractor (aka an eliminator) that allows the same right things to come out the other end.

Perhaps if you gave some explanation of why you're looking for a purer union type it would illuminate whether regular discriminated unions are sufficient or if you really need something more.

Comment: Yes I think this makes sense. The downside (but probably worth it given the problems with the other approaches) is that now for each of these Unions I have to write the above structure. Maybe a good use-case for a macro.

Comment: @Aish Yes, that is a good point. One way to make it nicer is to create a sealed parameterized trait, say called `Flavor`, with subclasses for all the different "types" your system supports, and concrete methods for the core type-related operations. Then, any structure that would normally be parameterized over a type can be parameterized over a Flavor. You still need that big discriminated union, but this way it only needs to happen in one place.

Comment: I suppose my hacky `(A with B)` type is playing a similar role to a super type, such as the sealed trait Foo in your answer. Either way would require you to pattern match from the super type down to the specific subtype you need.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason every JSON parser for Scala requires well defined types into which the JSON will be converted, even if some fields have to be dropped: you cannot work with something you don't know the type of.

To given an example, say you have `a`, and maybe `a` is a `String`, maybe it's an `Int`, but you don't know *what* it is. Why computation could you possibly make with `a`, not knowing its type? Why would your code compute the sum of all `a`'s, for instance, if you didn't know in advance it was a number?

Generally, the answer to that is to perform user-provided data manipulation at runtime over data with unknown characteristics, as the user itself sees that it's a number and decides they want to know what the sum of that field is. Fine, but you are going the wrong way about it if so.

There *is* a well defined way to represent JSON data in Scala (and, for that matter, any data that has the same characteristics as JSON. Which is using a hierarchy of classes. A json value may be a json object, array or one of a number of primitives. A json object contains a list of key/value pairs, whose keys are json strings and values are json values. And so on. This is easy to represent, and there are many library doing so already. In fact, there are so many that there's a project called [Json4s](http://json4s.org/) which presents a unified API which can be used and is implemented by many of the aforementioned libraries.

Things like the records which Miles Sabin's [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library provide are intended to be used when the input doesn't have a well defined schema, but the *program* knows what it needs from that input. And, yes, the program might know what to do with `a` if it is an `Int` or a `String`, but not every possible value.

Comment: I'm writing a macro to be used on top of Circe (http://circe.io) to do code-gen of the case-classes. Most of the Json libraries are for encoding / decoding to a set of case-classes, since those are the actual model you're using within the app. In my case I also have a json-schema file (http://json-schema.org/) so it's *desirable* for me to automate generating the model as well (in my case the provider of the json-schema is updating the schema frequently, and I'm getting sick of staying on top of those updates ;) )

Comment: To put that a bit more clearly. I'm writing a macro to generate case classes (my model), encoders, and decoders, from a given Json schema file. It's on top of Circe, which is used to do the actual Json wrangling. I want to hide the Json types as much as possible from the end-user, since that's a serialization concern, and  should be seamless to them.

Answer (score 2):

The next Scala 3 (mid 2020) based on [Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty) will implement the [proposal for Union Type](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-add-union-types-to-the-language/2352) from last Sept. 2018

You see it in "[a tour of Scala 3](https://www.slideshare.net/Odersky/a-tour-of-scala-3?qid=c767bca7-b174-4d27-9d0e-79dd9dfcfb4f&v=&b=&from_search=1)" (June 2019)

> - Union Types Provide ad-hoc combinations of types
> - Subsetting = Subtyping
> - No boxing overhead

```
case class UserName(name: String) 
case class Password(hash: Hash) 

def help(id: UserName | Password) = {
  val user = id match { 
    case UserName(name) => lookupName(name) 
    case Password(hash) => lookupPassword(hash) 
  } 
  ... 
}
```

> - Union Types Work also with singleton types
> - Great for JS interop

```
type Command = "Click" | "Drag" | "KeyPressed" 

def handleEvent(kind: Command) = kind match {
  case "Click" => MouseClick() 
  case "Drag" => MoveTo() 
  case "KeyPressed" => KeyPressed() 
}
```