# Int and Char scala interpolation (generics and upper bounds)

Tags: scala, generics

I am playing with generics and upper bounds in scala and I am facing the following problem:

Let's say I have the following function (where I only expect either Int or Char):

```
def foo[T](tuple: Tuple2[T, T]) = tuple match {
  case Tuple2(x: Int, y: Int) => (x to y).toArray
  case Tuple2(x: Char, y: Char) => (x to y).toArray
}
```

I would expect to have a better and compressed form like:

```
def foo2[T >: Int with Char <: AnyVal](tuple: (T, T))  = (tuple._1 to tuple._2).toArray
```

But this is definitely not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the lower bound on `T` called `Int with Char`? What is that trying to do?

Comment: Sorry,, edited.

Comment: You want a union type I think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I updated the definition of foo2.

Comment: @ChrisShain I was trying to avoid the verbose of having 2 cases, instead of assuring that the T will be either an Int or Char (I can assume that it will only be one of these 2 types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to simply call `NumericRange.inclusive` yourself, rather than try to sort out the implicits and type constraints that would be needed to use the `to` syntax. If we require an implicit `Integral`, we'll know how to construct the range with a step of one (provided by the `Integral` instance). We'll also need a `ClassTag[A]` to create the `Array` generically:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange

def foo2[A >: Int with Char : ClassTag](tuple: (A, A))(implicit int: Integral[A]) = 
   NumericRange.inclusive(tuple._1, tuple._2, int.one).toArray

scala> foo2(('a', 'z'))
res13: Array[Char] = Array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)

scala> foo2((1, 10))
res14: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Others fail (if you want them to with the type constraint):

```
scala> foo2((1L, 10L))
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter int: Integral[AnyVal]
       foo2((1L, 10L))
           ^
```

Comment: Just one thing, the final array should also contain the second char/int: `foo2((1, 10))` should return `Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`

Comment: @jalv1039 Updated to use `NumericRange.inclusive`, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relatively-horrifying signature you can use to get the `(tup._1 to tup._2).toArray` syntax on your implementation:

```
def foo[T 
  <% RangedProxy[T]{ type ResultWithoutStep <: TraversableOnce[T] } 
  : ClassTag
](tup: (T, T))
```

Breaking it down:
T is implicitly convertable to a `RangedProxy[T]`, which is where the `to` method is defined. The result type of `to` depends on the *type member* `ResultWithoutStep`, which we must ensure is a subclass of `TraversableOnce[T]` so that we can call `.toArray` on it.

Note that neither the above signature or @MichaelZajac's answer will handle your requested functionality of "only work with Int and Char". Really, the best approach to satisfy that would be to use a *typeclass*.

```
sealed trait Fooable[T] extends ((T, T) => Array[T])
object Fooable {
  private def impl[T](f: (T, T) => Array[T]) = 
    new Fooable[T]{ def apply(min: T, max: T): Array[T] = f(min, max) }
  implicit val intFooable = impl[Int]{ (i,j) => (i to j).toArray }
  implicit val charFooable = impl[Char]{ (a,b) => (a to b).toArray }
}
def foo[T: Fooable](tup: (T, T)) = implicitly[Fooable[T]].apply(tup._1, tup._2)
```

Unfortunately, the typeclass approach is a bit cumbersome for this particular problem, but if you focus on the `implicit val xFooable` you'll find that it's kind of similar to the following:

```
// unfortunately this doesn't work due to type erasure on the JVM,
// which is why we've resorted to typeclasses as above
def foo(tup: (Int, Int)) = ...
def foo(tup: (Char, Char)) = ...
```

Comment: Adding `>: Int with Char` to mine will limit it to `Int` and `Char`, though there's little practical reason to enforce it, as `Integral` prevents client code from using another type that would otherwise break it.