# Scala type constraint

Tags: scala, class

I have the following classes

```
case class A(vl: Int)
case class B(name: String)
```

now I want to create a class like this

```
case class Cllction[T](objs: Seq[T])
```

But the thing is I want to restrict to be only either `A` or `B`. Is it possible to do so in Scala? I mean for example if I try to create like this:

```
val s = Seq[Int]()
val c = Cllction(s) // should be compile error
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way is to use a common base (a marker trait), which you then use for a type bound:

```
trait Col
case class A(vl: Int) extends Col
case class B(name: String) extends Col

case class Cllction[T <: Col](objs: Seq[T])
```

If you cannot modify `A` and `B`, other solution would be union types, but that requires is a lot more complex code or using a library. See [How to define “type disjunction” (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types)

Comment: Note that in this case you can also have `Cllction[Col]` instead of `Cllction[A]` or `Cllction[B]`. The top answer in the linked question doesn't have this problem.