# Return result without losing type

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

I am trying to create partial function at the end of the step. Here is my adt to represent result of the process.

```
sealed trait Result

object Result {

  case class Success[T](result: T) extends Result

  case class Fail(cause: String) extends Result

}
```

This is my representation of the processing. Basically they are function.

```
  sealed trait Action[A, B] {
    type ActionT <: ActionType.type
    val function:(A) => Either[String, B]
    def apply(v1: A): Result = function(v1) match {
      case Right(v2) => Success(v2)
      case Left(cause) => Fail(cause)
    }
  }

  sealed trait ActionType

  object ActionType {
    case object Pre extends ActionType
    case object Post extends ActionType
  }

  case class ActionA(function: Int => Either[String, String]) extends Action[Int, String]
  {
    override type ActionT = ActionType.Pre.type
  }

  case class ActionB(function: Int => Either[String, Int => Double]) extends Action[String, Int => Double]
  {
    override type ActionT = ActionType.Post.type
  }
```

Normally, I have about ten actions. However, to explain the problem, two are enough.

I want to create a merging function. It will create a partial function like

```
  val pf = {
    case ActionType.Pre => //actiona instance
    case ActionType.Post => //actionb instanse
  }
```

and if I want to query for ActionType.Pre to this partial function, I should get actionA instance. ActionA is just a function that wants Integer as a parameter and return Success(**result**) basically. Here is the problem. In application, I want to know the type of the **result** which is string for this case, and a function(Int => Double) for actionb.

How can I know the result type?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want by "How can I know the result type"? Do you want the `pf` function to return something like `Either[Success[String], Success[Int => Double]]`?

Comment: Pf function will have hundreds of case. I cannot just deal with Either, I guess. And I want to know the result type when I give one of ActionType as a parameter. For example:

case ActionType.Pre => Instance of A (Action[Int, String])
case ActionType.Post => Instance of B ( Action[String, Int => Double])

Comment: So it looks like you need an union type of hundreds of different types. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types