# Short denotation of sum type in Scala

Tags: scala

Does sum type have short denotation in Scala?

For example:

Product type -(Integer, Double)

Funtion type -(Integer=>Double)

Sum type -?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define "type disjunction" (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types)

Comment: @DmytroMitin I somehow got the impression that *sum types* are specifically **tagged** union types (`Either`, scalaz's `\/`), both of your links seem to be about untagged union types, which are more about subtyping, not about disjoint unions? The "default category" (types, functions) and the subtyping poset are slightly different things... Maybe OP could clarify what exactly they want to know (in particular, what's the problem with `Either`? It's not *that* long, given that it's not used all *that* often.)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sum+type

Comment: @DmytroMitin Well, yes... Now, you first proposed the duplicate mentioning [union types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979396/2707792), which are essentially more like a join in the `<:`-poset, whereas the nlab link speaks specifically about the disjoint union / the coproduct (with separate `inl`, `inr` inclusions). It holds `implicitly[Int | Int =:= Int]`, but not `implicitly[Either[Int, Int] =:= Int]` (at least in Dotty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, the sum type constructor is given by `scala.util.Either`. If you need tagged sum of more than two types (e.g. `A`, `B`, `C`), then it usually makes sense to create a custom sealed trait:

```
sealed trait AorBorC

case class CaseA(a: A) extends AorBorC
case class CaseB(b: B) extends AorBorC
case class CaseC(c: C) extends AorBorC
```

and then work with pattern matching.

You can of course define shortcuts, if you want:

```
type +[A, B] = Either[A, B]
type \/[A, B] = Either[A, B]
```

and then use them in infix notation `A + B` or `A \/ B`.

You can also use `\/` from ScalaZ.

---

The `util.Either` is indeed the coproduct as explained [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sum+type):

- Formation: for any two types `A, B`, you can form the type `Either[A, B]` (there are no restrictions)
- Introduction: if `a: A` and `b: B`, then both `Left(a)` and `Right(b)` are values of type `Either[A, B]`.
- Elimination: if `e: Either[A, B]`, then the usual pattern matching can be used to collapse both cases to a single type `C`:

  ```
  e match {
    case Left(a) => c1(a) // assuming `c1(a): C`
    case Right(b) => c2(b) // assuming `c2(b): C`
  }
  ```

  There is also `fold`:

  ```
  e.fold(c1, c2)
  ```

  which does essentially the same, and also produces a value of type `C`. The meaning should be clear:

  ```
  Left(a).fold(c1, c2) == c1(a)
  Right(b).fold(c1, c2) == c2(b)
  ```

This is indeed *the sum type* of `A` and `B`, because for any other type `C` and any two functions `c1: A => C`, `c2: B => C` there is the function `(e: Either[A, B]) => e.fold(c1, c2)`, for which the above two identities hold, which is exactly the universal property required by the definition of a coproduct.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no syntactic sugar for defining *sum types* in Scala. In fact, Scala does not have *sum types* in its type system as a distinct feature. They need to be encoded somehow, the most widely-used encoding is as closed subtyping hierarchies, i.e. the *sum type*

```
A = B + C
```

is encoded as

```
sealed trait A

final class B extends A
final class C extends A
```

Note that Scala also does not have syntactic sugar for *product types* either. The syntax you mentioned is for *tuple types*, not *product types*. Tuple types are merely one of many different classes of product types. E.g. *`case class`es* are another class of product types.

Note also that Scala does not have a notion of *product types* in its type system either. They are encoded as *parametric types* that are subtypes of one of the `ProductN` types. I.e. the *tuple type* `(A, B)` is actually syntactic sugar for

```
Tuple2[A, B]
```

which is defined as

```
final case class Tuple2[+A, +B](_1: A, _2: B) extends Product2[A, B] with Product with Serializable
```

Of course, classes and traits can be seen as variants of records, so in some sense, every type in Scala can be seen as a product type, which is why it is so easy to encode them.

Comment: I *explicitly* say that tuple types *are* one of many classes of product types.