# How to make a list contain ints and strings? A challenge using lists only

Tags: scala

I am beginning in scala and I need to contain a bunch of ints, and something other than a `number` in a `List`.

For example `List(4,null)` or `List(4,"STOPSTR")`.

- How would I declare a variable of type `List[Int or String]` (Kind
  of)?
- Also, is it at all possible to declare a variable for a list that can
  only contain a certain string. E.g. `List[Int or String=="STOPSTR"]`
  and have it checked at compile time.

For the reasons of a challenge, I can only use Lists for this exercise, no classes, no maps, not even Arrays.

Comment: This first one will be available on **Scala 3**. The second is possible using **Refined** types _(but those are only available on external libraries)_. - In general, this seems like a code smell, **Lists** are homogeneous data structures. Can you share what is the challenge you want to solve and what have you tried?

Comment: Well I have to say that challenge is not very good, in vanilla Scala that is not possible without "hacks". Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types/6312508#6312508
If you really want to do it.
Curious to see the challenge if you can provided

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually, this would be a literal type (which are part of Scala 2.13), not a refined type.

Comment: Why you need it? I use Scala about 3 year, and I doesn't need to use something like `List[Int or String]` (but sometimes I want use `Double or Int`).
You can create own type for Int and String and convert both types to your type, if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it 2 different ways:

1. The first is using `Any` as the type parameter to `List`. The problem here though, is that it's not constrained to just `Int` and `String` types. You could add any other type to the list as well.

E.g.

```
List[Any](1, 2, "Three")
```

2. The second is to use `Either`. Either has a `Left` and a `Right` type that can be different. e.g.

```
List[Either[Int, String]](Left(1), Left(2), Right("Three"))
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Scala you can do as following:

```
val myList: List[Int | String] = List(1, 2, "Hello", "World")
```

Edited:
Scala 3.0 or higher