# How to override Scala generic methods for specific types?

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I currently have something like this:

```
case class Bear(a: String, b: String) {
   val can: Can[T] = ?? 
   def drink[T](str: String) = can.open(str)
}
```

I need to modify this to be used for only 4 types A,B,C and D. For example given an instance of Bear we should only be able to call `bearinstance.drink[A]("abc")`, `bearinstance.drink[B]("abc")`, `bearinstance.drink[C]("abc")` and `bearinstance.drink[D]("abc")`. Any other type should not be allowed.

Now the question is how do I rewrite this method for specific types?

Another issue is with the `can`, assuming I manage to rewrite `drink` to be used with only types 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D', I will have to create `can` for all the four types as member variables. How do I make generic method to dynamically select the `can` based on the type? One option is to implicitly declare `can` outside the class, but it requires class parameters to be declared.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: They're type parameters, not class parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you need to do this means you really should refactor your code.

But anyways...

Try using implicit parameters:

```
case class Bear(a: String, b: String) {
   val can: Can[T] = ???
   def drink[T](str: String)(implicit ev: CanDrink[T]) = can.open(str)
}
```

Then make a trait `CanDrink` with implicit instances:

```
trait CanDrink[T]
implicit object ACanDrink extends CanDrink[A]
implicit object BCanDrink extends CanDrink[B]
//And so on
```

And now you can call it like this:

```
bearinstance.drink[A]("abc") 
//Gets implicit object ACanDrink

bearinstance.drink[X]("abc") 
//Doesn't work because no implicit parameter given of type CanDrink[X]
```

In Dotty, you could try changing the definition of drink using union types, as suggested by Dmytro Mitin:

```
def drink(x: A | B | C | D)(str: String) = ???
def drink[T](str: String)(using T <:< (A | B | C | D)) = ???
```

If you need it to be determined dynamically, use `ClassTag`.

```
def drink[T](str: String)(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = ev match {
  case classOf[A] => ???
  ...
}
```

Comment: I did think of creating implicit objects but I need class parameters to initialize them.

Comment: @Bugman I've edited my answer now to dynamically determine it

Comment: @user `A | B | C | D` is a type, you can't use it like `def drink[A | B | C | D](str: String) = ???` (at least in Dotty 0.25), you can use it like `def drink(x: A | B | C | D)(str: String) = ???` or `def drink[T](str: String)(using T <:< (A | B | C | D)) = ???`

Comment: I've modified my answer now

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually **overriding** generic method you must implement it for all possible types of type parameters (otherwise you violate the contract of class):

```
trait BearLike {
  def drink[T](str: String)
}

case class Bear(a: String, b: String) extends BearLike {
  override def drink[T](str: String) = ??? // for all T
}
```

or

```
case class Bear(a: String, b: String) {
  def drinkABCD[T](str: String)(implicit can: Can[T]) = can.open(str) // only for A, ..., D
}
```

or

```
case class Bear(a: String, b: String) extends BearLike {
  override def drink[T](str: String): Unit = sys.error("Bear is not actually a BearLike")
  def drinkABCD[T](str: String)(implicit can: Can[T]) = can.open(str) // only for A, ..., D
}
```

provided there are `Can[A]`, ..., `Can[D]`

```
trait Can[T] {
  def open(str: String)
}
object Can {
  implicit val a: Can[A] = ???
  implicit val b: Can[B] = ???
  implicit val c: Can[C] = ???
  implicit val d: Can[D] = ???
}
```

If you can modify the contract then you can add this restriction (that the method works only for `A`, ..., `D`) to the contract

```
trait BearLike {
  def drink[T](str: String)(implicit can: Can[T])
}

case class Bear(a: String, b: String) extends BearLike {
  override def drink[T](str: String)(implicit can: Can[T]) = can.open(str)
}
```

Sometimes it's not easy to combine FP (type classes) with OOP (inheritance). Normally if you start to work with type classes (`Can`) you should prefer type classes further on

```
trait BearLike[B] {
  def drink(str: String)
}

case class Bear[T](a: String, b: String) 
object Bear {
  implicit def bearIsBearLike[T](implicit can: Can[T]): BearLike[Bear[T]] = new BearLike[Bear[T]] {
    override def drink(str: String): Unit = can.open(str)
  }
}
```

[How to define "type disjunction" (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types)