# Does shapeless for Scala 2 has analogue for Scala 3 union types?

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, union-types

Scala 3 has very convenient [Union types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-union.html). I'm looking for something closer in `shapeless` for Scala 2 that would allow similar behavior. Example:

```
case class Cs1()
case class Cs2()
```

I tried `shapeless.v`, but it does not seem to work as I thought it to.

```
val v: Cs1 v Cs2 = Cs1() // compile error
```

The error:

```
[error]  found   : example.Hello.Cs1
[error]  required: example.Hello.Cs1 ∨ example.Hello.Cs2
```

Is there something in shapeless for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shapeless.∨` is for context bounds, you  can't use it in return type.

```
def foo[T: (Cs1 |∨| Cs2)#λ] = ???

foo[Cs1] // compiles
foo[Cs2] // compiles
foo[Int] // doesn't compile
```

See also

[How to define "type disjunction" (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312508/5249621)

[Shapeless type disjunction for more then 2 types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173145/shapeless-type-disjunction-for-more-then-2-types)

https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/