# Scala 2.13 Case Class: Union of multiple case classes?

Tags: scala, union-types, sum-type

I have 3 case classes in Scala:

```
case class Teacher(name: String, subject: String, age: Int)
```

```
case class Student(name: String, subject: String, section: String, class: Int)
```

```
case class School(user: Teacher | Student)
```

In the third case class, the User could either be Teacher or Student but it has to be only one of them. How can I achieve the same syntactically in Scala 2.13?

Edit 1: As suggested in comments, Either does seem convenient but what if:

```
case class School(user: Teacher | Student | Principal)
```

Edit 2:

If I use a sealed trait as suggest in comments:

```
sealed trait SchoolUser
case class Student(name: String, subject: String, section: String, `class`: Int)
  case class Teacher(name: String, subject: String, age: Int)
  case class Principal(name: String, year: Int)

  case object Student extends SchoolUser
  case object Teacher extends SchoolUser
  case object Principal extends SchoolUser

  case class School(user: SchoolUser)

  val school = School(user = ???)

  println("Complete")
```

But I am confused on how to instantiate the case class as in line:

```
val school = School(user = ???) // Principal(name="ABC",year=2022)
```

Edit 4: Finally got all the answers

Comment: Why not `Either`?

Comment: Well, either using `Either` or make both `Teacher` and `Student` part of the same ADT.

Comment: Either would work only for two variables right? What if `case class School(user: Teacher | Student | Principal)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what does making part of same ADT mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916845/does-shapeless-for-scala-2-has-analogue-for-scala-3-union-types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173145/shapeless-type-disjunction-for-more-then-2-types

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, for two cases `Either` works fine however for Three or More an ADT would suit with a sealed trait:

```
sealed trait SchoolUser
  case class Student(name: String, subject: String, section: String, `class`: Int) extends SchoolUser
  case class Teacher(name: String, subject: String, age: Int) extends SchoolUser
  case class Principal(name: String, year: Int) extends SchoolUser


  case class School(user: SchoolUser)

  val schoolPrincipal:SchoolUser = Principal("Name",123)

  println("Complete")
```