# Generic type compiled classes for common handling

Tags: java, scala, generics

I've 10 data transfer objects that i received through a maven dependency. I would like to type these objects with an abstract class or an interface so I can handle them as one type and not separately.

Since the classes are compiled and imported through maven I cannot change the classes itself.

The reason behind this is for me to handle them as one common type so I for example can send each one of them inside the same function.

```
public void build(CommonDTO commonDto) {
......
}
```

I need to solve this in Scala. But I can try to translate it to Scala if a Java solution is found.

Comment: You can either use a **typeclass** or a wrapper.; in this case, maybe a wrapper is best. - You may also try with structural types. - https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

Comment: `type CommonDTO = A | B | C | D`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types