# found Unit: required [Something Else]

Tags: scala, if-statement

My code is:

```
   var storage: Storage =
    if (config.storageType == StorageType.MAP)
      MapStorage()
    else if (config.storageType == StorageType.LIST)
      ListStorage()
    else ()
```

The error I am receiving is

```
[E007] Type Mismatch Error
Found:    Unit                                                                                                                                                     
Required: ****.utils.Storage
```

*** is just placed to omit the actual value. I know that there is no stand-alone if statement in scala and hence the last else() statement is present in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return `()` having type `Unit` if you promised to return `Storage` (`storage: Storage`).

Either return a `Storage`

```
val storage: Storage =
  if (config.storageType == StorageType.MAP)
    MapStorage()
  else if (config.storageType == StorageType.LIST)
    ListStorage()
  else MapStorage() // or ListStorage() or some other storage
```

or make one of the cases default

```
val storage: Storage =
  if (config.storageType == StorageType.MAP)
    MapStorage()
  else // default case
    ListStorage()
```

or if you really can't return any of storages in the default case, return `null` (it's worse since this can lead to `NullPointerException` in the code for unknown reason)

```
val storage: Storage =
  if (config.storageType == StorageType.MAP)
    MapStorage()
  else if (config.storageType == StorageType.LIST)
    ListStorage()
  else null 

// null has type `Null`, which is a subtype of any reference type, e.g. Storage
// Null <: Storage
// Null | Storage =:= Storage
```

or throw exception with a proper message (it's better than returning `null`)

```
val storage: Storage =
  if (config.storageType == StorageType.MAP)
    MapStorage()
  else if (config.storageType == StorageType.LIST)
    ListStorage()
  else throw new RuntimeException("unexpected storage type")

// throwing exception has type Nothing, which is a subtype of any type, e.g. Storage
// Nothing <: Null <: Storage
// Nothing | Storage =:= Storage
```

or change signature to `Option` (it's even better than throwing but you'll probably have to fix also places where `storage` is used)

```
val storage: Option[Storage] =
  if (config.storageType == StorageType.MAP)
    Some(MapStorage())
  else if (config.storageType == StorageType.LIST)
    Some(ListStorage())
  else None
```

Technically, you can return union type `Unit | Storage` in Scala 3 (or its [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types) in Scala 2) but such signature would be weird.