# Scala: Taking an array with one function inside as an argument

Tags: scala

I'm trying to define an array of numbers with the last being a function. It'll probably be better to give an example:

```
def myArrayFunc(foo:String, bar:Array[Int[Function1]]) // ?
myArrayFunc("foo", (1,2,3 (myFunction)))
```

Is this possible using Scala? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question as stated is nonsensical, because a function is not a number. But if you meant an array of numbers and also a function, then you can do:

```
def myArrayFunc(foo:String, bar: Array[Either[Int, Function1[A, B]]])
```

or if you prefer efficiency over  type safety:

```
def myArrayFunc(foo:String, bar: Array[Any])
```

But it would really make more sense to do:

```
def myArrayFunc(foo:String, bar: Array[Int], f: Function1[A, B])
```

Replace `A` and `B` with appropriate types in the above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but you cannot use an `Array`; you need something like a `Vector`.  This is further answered here: [How do I create a heterogeneous Array in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185972/arrays-in-scala)

Comment: `Array` works perfectly fine: `val a = Array(1, 2, (x: Int) => x)`. The accepted linked answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `Array[Int]` with an element that is a function as long as the function returns an `Int` since all elements in a Scala `Array` must have the same type.

```
def myArrayFunc(foo:String, bar:Array[Int]) = bar.map(_ + foo) 

scala> def plusOne(i:Int) = i + 1
plusOne: (i: Int)Int

scala> myArrayFunc("foo", Array(1,2,plusOne(2)))
res22: Array[String] = Array(1foo, 2foo, 3foo)
```